# Remove accents from a JSON response

Tags: php, json

I get back a JSON response from a social networks site. There are certain accented characters that I would like to be removed.

An example is : L\u00e1szl\u00f3 M\u00e1rton, that reads "László Márton" and I would like to be transformed into Laszlo Marton.

I would like to keep the JSON format intact, as I will send it towards.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See accepted anwser to: [How do I remove accents from characters in a PHP string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017599/how-do-i-remove-accents-from-characters-in-a-php-string)

```
$input = "Fóø Bår";

setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");
$output = iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", $input);

print($output);
```

if server is correctly configured (as the reference question states) this should work.

**Edit: it doesn't.**

This will do :)

```
$string = current(json_decode('["L\u00e1szl\u00f3 M\u00e1rton"]'));

$a = 'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûýýþÿŔŕ';
$b = 'aaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuuybsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnoooooouuuyybyRr';
$string = utf8_decode($string);
$string = strtr($string, utf8_decode($a), $b);

echo $string; // output > Laszlo Marton
```

Comment: Can I use this on the raw string format of JSON? Will this cause mailformation in the JSON structure?

Comment: Use it after decoding JSON. In theory, you could also replace within the JSON representation itself (using unicode codes like \u00e1 as the source).

Answer (score 0):

you can try the functions here http://hsivonen.iki.fi/php-utf8/