# How to remove accents and turn letters into "plain" ASCII characters?

Tags: php, regex, string, ascii

What is the most efficient way to remove accents from a string e.g. `ÈâuÑ` becomes `Eaun`?

Is there a simple, built in way that I'm missing or a regular expression?

Comment: @Peeps: telling users to search google is against Stack Overflow's etiquette. If the question doesn't exist on the website it's better for everyone if it is asked, even if the OP already knows the answer, since it will increase our number of non-duplicate questions. So maybe next time if someone searches it with google they will find this very question, and we will have one more user.

Comment: @Andreas good point. However, this is most certainly a SO duplicate, so Peeps kind of has a small point :) I'm too lazy to search for it right now, though.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If you have iconv installed, try this (the example assumes your input string is in UTF-8):

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
```

(iconv is a library to convert between all kinds of encodings; it's efficient and included with many PHP distributions by default. Most of all, it's definitely easier and more error-proof than trying to roll your own solution (did you know that there's a "Latin letter N with a curl"? [Me neither](http://www.decodeunicode.org/en/u+0235).))

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. This should work best. However, note that this tends to fail if there are invalid characters in the input (using `ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` should help) and as so often, if encountering problems, the User Contributed Notes are a good read. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Comment: For some reason, sometimes I can't get this to work. See http://codepad.viper-7.com/SUufA4 But in another machine, I got "`E^au~N". Not was desired, though.

Comment: Nice, simple and small and works...for me

Comment: This inconv has some conflicts so I will ask a similar question

Comment: This did not work for me at first. Accent characters just became ? characters. As per a comment on iconv() on the PHP manual page, I first ran: setlocale(LC_ALL,'en_CA.utf8'); and then everything worked perfectly. The 'en_CA.utf8' was the default locale on my system.  Try "locale -a" to see a list of available locales

Comment: This icon() solution works for many characters, but not all.  For example, "Colbjørnsensgade" becomes "Colbj?rnsensgade". That's why the transliterator_transliterate() solution by SimonSimCity is usually a better choice (but requires the right libraries installed to work).

Comment: This doesn't work for all russian characters

Comment: This fixed the question marks for me.
`setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");

$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);`

Comment: Just another upvote for these comments here. I spent a few hours today trying to debug why my ASCiI//TRANSLIT//IGNORE code wasn't working on a German a umlaut. My development platform worked fine. The live server failed. After trying a thousand things, the setlocale worked fine - added to to both.

Answer (score 57):

I found a solution, that worked in all my test-cases (copied from http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php):

```
var_dump(transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII; [\u0080-\u7fff] remove',
    "A æ Übérmensch på høyeste nivå! И я люблю PHP! есть. ﬁ ¦"));
// string(50) "A ae Ubermensch pa hoyeste niva! I a lublu PHP! est. fi "
```

see: http://www.php.net/normalizer

**EDIT:** This solution is independent of the locale set using *setlocale()*. Another benefit over *iconv()* is, that even non-latin characters are not ignored.

**EDIT2:** I discovered, that there are some characters, that are not covered by the transliteration I posted originally. `Any-Latin` translates the cyrillic character `ь` to a character, that doesn't fit into a latin character-set: `ʹ` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29). I've added `[\u0100-\u7fff] remove` to remove all these non-latin characters. I also added a test to the text ;)

I suggest, that they mean the latin alphabet and not one of the latin character-sets by `Latin` here. But anyways - in my opinion, they should transliterate it to something ASCII then in `Latin-ASCII` ...

**EDIT3:** Sorry for another change here. I had to take the characters down to u0080 instead of u0100, to get only ASCII characters as output. The test above is updated.

Comment: Note: it needs `php_intl.dll` extension enabled

Comment: I agree, this was the best function for me too! (and I tried many)

Comment: Really good solution, very easy to use and most useful that others solutions using str_replace.

Comment: Should be noted that this will not just transliterate the text (as OP asked), but will remove some chracters too. eg € (euro sign) will be removed. Just pass 'Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII;' as the first param to keep those. Optionally, you can then use iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $str) to transform "€" to "EUR".

Answer (score 19):

Reposting this on request of @palantir ...

I find iconv completely unreliable, and I dislike preg_replace solutions and big arrays ... so my favorite way (and the only reliable method I've found) is ...

```
function toASCII( $str )
{
    return strtr(utf8_decode($str), 
        utf8_decode(
        'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ'),
        'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy');
}
```

Comment: you should also put in the following letters: `ő`, `Ő`, `ű`, `Ű`. Thanks. :)

Comment: This is not reliable method. Not working for polish accented chars like `ŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓżźćńąśłęó`. Try `var_dump(strtr(utf8_decode('qqqqŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓżźćńąśłęóqqq'), utf8_decode('ŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓżźćńąśłęó'),'ZZCNASLEOzzcnasleo'));` I got `string(25) "qqqqeeeeeeeeOeeeeeeeeoqqq"`. Iconv is more reliable `var_dump(iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', 'qqqqŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓżźćńąśłęóqqq'));` and I get `string(25) "qqqqZZCNASLEOzzcnasleoqqq"`

Comment: converts 'Горловка' for me to  YYYYYYYY , not good

Comment: It's not the best in terms of performance and it also produces incorrect result. Letters like Œ, Æ, etc. should decompose to two letters, not to one.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `iconv` to transliterate the characters to plain US-ASCII and then use a regular expression to remove non-alphabetic characters:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', '', iconv("UTF-8", "US-ASCII//TRANSLIT", $text))
```

Another way would be using the [Normalizer](http://php.net/normalizer) to normalize to the [Normalization Form KD (NFKD)](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms) and then remove the mark characters:

```
preg_replace('/\p{Mn}/u', '', Normalizer::normalize($text, Normalizer::FORM_KD))
```

Comment: `ISO-8859-1`? Are you sure? Won't this leave at least ÄÖÜ in place (as their 8859-1 counterparts)?

Comment: What’s the reason for the down vote?

Comment: Downvote isn't mine. However, the OP is not asking to remove non-alphabetic characters, is he?

Comment: It was mine. Reverted now that you fixed it.

Comment: @Pekka: The transliteration of `ÈâuÑ` using `iconv` gives `\`E^au~N`. That’s why the following cleanup is used.

Comment: @Gumbo I see. I'm sorry, we have had this discussion in a duplicate somewhere already :) +1 for the most complete solution, then, that should be made the accepted one. *Update:* If I had any votes left

Comment: By the way, what you say and your code don't match once again. FORM_D makes more sense.

Comment: @Artefacto: Thanks for the remark; fixed it. And take a look at figure 6 in http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms.

Comment: @Gumbo OK, I guess it's a matter of preference, though strictly that normalization won't take care only of the marks. See also the other question of the OP. I took some, erm, inspiration from you (basically only replaced the [a-z] regex you then had with \p{M} and left Normalizer::FORM_D.

Comment: The normalize function works for me.

Comment: @Gumbo your `Normalizer` solution is quite good but in my case two characters `Ł` and `ł` are left untouched. My code: `var_dump(preg_replace('/\p{Mn}/u', '',Normalizer::normalize('qqqqŻŹĆŃĄŚŁĘÓżźćńąśłęóqqq', Normalizer::FORM_KD)));` and I get back: `string(27) "qqqqZZCNASŁEOzzcnasłeoqqq"`. `iconv` works best for me.

Answer (score 12):

Note: I'm reposting this from another similar question in the hope that it's helpful to others.

I ended up writing a PHP library based on URLify.js from the Django project, since I found iconv() to be too incomplete. You can find it here:

https://github.com/jbroadway/urlify

Handles Latin characters as well as Greek, Turkish, Russian, Ukrainian, Czech, Polish, and Latvian.

Comment: This class worked on all my testcases where all iconv-based solutions failed for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this class. In 2017 the project is still alive and the class is working perfectly in PHP7