# how to remove all utf-8 characted from string using php

Tags: php, encoding, utf8-decode

I have a problem as below.
I have one xml which contain utf-8 characters but the data of this xml will get displayed on page with iso encoding.

So I have to remove this utf-8 charactres from string, How can I do this.

Thanks
Avinash

**EDIT:**

I have used :
iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", str_replace('&','and',removeEmptyLines(strip_tags($value))))

and now its displaying Â in xml file.

How can I remove this...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP remove accents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542717/php-remove-accents)

Comment: remove or translate somehow to make it displayable?

Comment: Also, "ISO encoding" (assuming you mean `iso-8859`) is not a single encoding, it is divided into 16 parts (iso-8859-1 to iso-8859-16). You need to specify which one you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use the iconv function:

```
 iconv('utf-8','iso-8859-1//TRANSLIT',$text);
```

Comment: Probably 'iso-8859-1//TRANSLIT', considering the later comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent the Unicode characters with character references by using [`mb_convert_encoding`](http://php.net/mb_convert_encoding):

```
mb_substitute_character('entity');
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8');
```

With [`mb_substitute_character`](http://php.net/mb_substitute_character) you specify how invalid characters (characters of the input character set that are not present in the output character set) should be handled. In this case *entity* specifies to replace invalid characters by a corresponding [HTML character reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3).

Comment: @Avinash: `Â` is also in ISO 8859-1. That’s why it is not replaced.

Comment: What if I what to remove this? How can I remove this?

Comment: @Avinash: Why do you want to remove it if it can be used with ISO 8859-1?

Comment: I don't know why but my database Collation is utf8_general_ci and when I fetch data its displaying This character in data. But when I look into the table using phpmyadmin. data have nothig like Â in tabel.
What can be the problem?

Comment: @Avinash: There are more character encodings and collations that need to be considered. (See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html)