# Need to convert é to e in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP remove accents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542717/php-remove-accents)

The title says most of it, but anyways...

I am getting data from an input file and inside the data we will have the character é. For our purposes we want to convert that to a regular lower case e.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: This is called [transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transliteration).

Comment: Not an exact duplicate of the 3542717. OP isn't asking how to replace all accents.

Comment: @webbiedave: I think this is just a simplification of what he is actually doing. But I’m willing to reopen the question if I am wrong.

Comment: Do you just want to replace this single character or are you looking for a way to transliterate a text?

Comment: @Gumbo: It very well could be. Just wanted to point out that the closers have gone ahead and assumed what the OP desired. Either way, this is no doubt many dups of *other* search and replace questions out there and there are ample answers below so I think reopening is moot  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just that one character?  This seems too obvious... just replace it.

```
$str = "é";

$str = str_replace("é","e",$str);

echo $str;  // "e"
```

Comment: While this is correct it turns out that my problem was that in my input this é ended up not actually being recognized as an é, but something else completely. I tried your code and it did work (last time I trust what someone else said did not work).

Answer (score 2):

I'd use this:

[PHP Function: string strtr ( string $str , string $from , string $to )](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

from the PHP Site:

```
<?php
//In this form, strtr() does byte-by-byte translation
//Therefore, we are assuming a single-byte encoding here:
$addr = strtr($addr, "äåö", "aao");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$myText = str_replace( array('é'), array('e'), $myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

$string = str_replace('é','e',$string);