# Replace é with e in PHP

Tags: php

Hey, this is my first post on stackoverflow.

I'm trying to replace é with e and other similar special characters.  I've tried str_replace() and converting it from UTF-8 to ASCII but nothing seems to work.  When I convert it from UTF-8 to anything it just drops the é off.  When I use str_replace() it never catches it and the é is still there.

I have a feeling something is wrong internally on our server because my friend tried str_replace() on his server and it worked fine.

Thanks,

Jason Tolhurst

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need to convert é to e in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125658/need-to-convert-e-to-e-in-php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$string = iconv('utf-8','ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT',$string);
```

Comment: yeah that drops the e off the end.

Comment: It doesn't here.....Can you reach the command line, and see if both charsets are supported with `iconv -l`? And what does `mb_detect_encoding($string);` say about the probably character set of the string (it might not be utf-8)?

Comment: I can get there how do I check it?

Comment: Oops typed it wrong the first time.  Yes both ASCII and UTF-8 are supported.  We tested this code and str_replace on another page on the same server and they functions as expected.  So something else is wrong here with our script :P Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I'd still say the input-charset isn't utf-8 :) What happens if you try one of the usual other input suspects (iso-8859-15, cp1252. etc.)?

Comment: From the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php): "If you append the string *//IGNORE*, characters that cannot be represented in the target charset are silently discarded." - I had to remove `//IGNORE` to make it [work](https://rextester.com/GNJG65315)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `htmlentities()` to convert `é` to `&eacute;` and then use a regex to pull out the first character after an ampersand.

```
function RemoveAccents($string) {
    // From http://theserverpages.com/php/manual/en/function.str-replace.php
    $string = htmlentities($string);
    return preg_replace("/&([a-z])[a-z]+;/i", "$1", $string);
}
```

Comment: Yay for `&euro;`, `&plusmn;`, `&frac14;`,`&amp;` and [loads of others](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/sgml/entities.html), IMHO you're introducing new problems, although the original problem is solved indeed.

Comment: You're quite right, though that may or may not be a problem, depending on the use-case.

Comment: `$string = preg_replace(array('/&szlig;/', '/&(..)lig;/', '/&([aeioucyAEIOUCY])(uml|acute|ring|cedil|circ|tilde|grave|slash);/', '/&(.)[^;]*;/'), array('ss', "$1", "$1", ""), $string);`

Answer (score 2):

See [the php manual page for `strtr()`](http://www.php.net/strtr)

The examples on this page deal with exactly your situation.

Hope that helps.