# How to use PHP array_multisort with accented characters

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, accent-sensitive

I currently have a multidimensional array I am sorting using array_multisort, however one of the columns has some special accented characters - for example `Développé`.

Is there a way to sort these characters with their equivalent non accented letter `é` = `e`?

```
array_multisort($column1, SORT_ASC,SORT_STRING|SORT_FLAG_CASE, $column2, SORT_ASC,SORT_STRING|SORT_FLAG_CASE, $multid_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126135/replace-%C3%A9-with-e-in-php) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3371697/1529324) here on SO regarding this issue, but when I tried them in the past, it seemed that most of them were too dependant on the locale of the system or even [str_replace with incomplete arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16427125/1529324). So running the code would either create different results on different environment or would miss a couple of characters.

In the end I found the best approach comes from this [non-accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26514376/1529324). From my tests this approach works perfectly, independently from all local settings, and can be adapted for accents only `è` or different sets like `æ`

The base is the [Transliterator class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php), part of the [intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension. which is available from PHP 5.4 onwards. In most system it's either already bundled or can be installed with

```
pecl install intl`
```

More installation info [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php).

### Usage

How to use is quite straightforward

1. **Step 1:** you initialise the Transliterator object

```
$transliterator = Transliterator::createFromRules(':: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: NFC;', Transliterator::FORWARD);
```

For a list of rules that can be applied to this function, please refer [to this manual](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-39/tr35-general.html). The ones used in the example already work for your specific use case.

2. **Step 2:** you use it to transliterate your text

```
$newstring = $transliterator->transliterate($string);
```

In your specific case, you need of course to apply to all the relevant elements of your array.

You're not sharing the array structure, so I can not produce a clear example, but depending on the structure you can use `foreach` or [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) or recursive functions to loop and change where needed.
If you want to update your initial question with a sample from the array, we can be more precise.