# Force encode from US-ASCII to UTF-8 (iconv)

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, iconv

I'm trying to transcode a bunch of files from US-ASCII to UTF-8.

For that, I'm using iconv:

```
iconv -f US-ASCII -t UTF-8 file.php > file-utf8.php
```

My original files are US-ASCII encoded, which makes the conversion not happen. Apparently it occurs because ASCII is a subset of UTF-8...

*[iconv US ASCII to UTF-8 or ISO-8859-15](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/iconv-us-ascii-to-utf-8-or-iso-8859-15-a-705054/)*

And quoting:

> There's no need for the textfile to appear otherwise until non-ASCII
>   characters are introduced

True. If I introduce a non-ASCII character in the file and save it, let's say with [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), the file encoding (charset) is switched to UTF-8.

In my case, I'd like to **force iconv to transcode the files to UTF-8 anyway**. Whether there is non-ASCII characters in it or not.

Note: The reason is my PHP code (non-ASCII files...) is dealing with some non-ASCII string, which causes the strings not to be well interpreted (french):

> Il Ã©tait une fois... l'homme sÃ©rie animÃ©e mythique d'Albert
>
> BarillÃ© (Procidis), 1Ã¨re
>
> ...

- `US ASCII` -- **is** -- a subset of `UTF-8` (see [Ned's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11303410/925307) below)
- Meaning that US ASCII files **are** actually encoded in `UTF-8`
- My problem came from somewhere else

Comment: can you remember where your problem came from? I am having a similar issue

Comment: @DrogoNevets Don't remember exactly but I think it has to do with working with UTF8 in PHP and to/from the DB...

`utf8_encode`, `utf8_decode`, etc...

Or more in depth:
http://www.toptal.com/php/a-utf-8-primer-for-php-and-mysql
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: To do the opposite (utf8 to ASCII), see [How to remove accents and turn letters into “plain” ASCII characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542717/how-to-remove-accents-and-turn-letters-into-plain-ascii-characters).

Answer (score 96, accepted):

ASCII is a subset of UTF-8, so all ASCII files are already UTF-8 encoded.  The bytes in the ASCII file and the bytes that would result from "encoding it to UTF-8" would be exactly the same bytes.  There's no difference between them, so there's no need to do anything.

It looks like your problem is that the files are not actually ASCII.  You need to determine what encoding they are using, and transcode them properly.

Answer (score 63):

## Short Answer

- `iconv` will use whatever input/output encoding you specify regardless of what the contents of the file are.  If you specify the wrong input encoding, the output will be garbled.
- You can try to use the `file` command to detect a file's type/encoding.
- `file` only guesses at the file encoding and may be wrong (especially in cases where special characters only appear late in large files).
- even after running `iconv`, `file` may not report any change due to the limited way in which `file` attempts to guess at the encoding. For a specific example, see my long answer.
- you can use `hexdump` to look at bytes of non-7-bit-ASCII text and compare against code tables for common encodings (ISO 8859-*, UTF-8) to decide for yourself what the encoding is.
- 7-bit ASCII (aka US ASCII) is identical at a byte level to UTF-8 and the 8-bit ASCII extensions (ISO 8859-*).  So if your file only has 7-bit characters, then you can call it UTF-8, ISO 8859-* or US ASCII because at a byte level they are all identical. It only makes sense to talk about UTF-8 and other encodings (in this context) once your file has characters outside the 7-bit ASCII range.

## Long Answer

I ran into this today and came across your question.  Perhaps I can add a little more information to help other people who run into this issue.

### ASCII

First, the term ASCII is overloaded, and that leads to confusion.

7-bit ASCII only includes 128 characters (00-7F or 0-127 in decimal). 7-bit ASCII is also sometimes referred to as US-ASCII.

*[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)*

### UTF-8

UTF-8 encoding uses the same encoding as 7-bit ASCII for its first 128 characters. So a text file that only contains characters from that range of the first 128 characters will be identical at a byte level whether encoded with UTF-8 or 7-bit ASCII.

*[Codepage layout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Codepage_layout)*

### ISO 8859-* and other ASCII Extensions

> The term *extended ASCII* (or *high ASCII*) refers to eight-bit or larger character encodings that include the standard seven-bit ASCII characters, plus additional characters.

*[Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII)*

ISO 8859-1 (aka "ISO Latin 1") is a specific 8-bit ASCII extension standard that covers most characters for Western Europe. There are other ISO standards for Eastern European languages and Cyrillic languages. ISO 8859-1 includes encoding for characters like Ö, é, ñ and ß for German and Spanish (UTF-8 supports these characters too, but the underlying encoding is different).

"Extension" means that ISO 8859-1 includes the 7-bit ASCII standard and adds characters to it by using the 8th bit. So for the first 128 characters, ISO 8859-1 is equivalent at a byte level to both ASCII and UTF-8 encoded files. However, when you start dealing with characters beyond the first 128, you are no longer UTF-8 equivalent at the byte level, and you must do a conversion if you want your "extended ASCII" encoded file to be UTF-8 encoded.

*[ISO 8859 and proprietary adaptations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII#ISO_8859_and_proprietary_adaptations)*

Before the ISO 8-bit ascii extension standards (`ISO 8859-*`) were released, there were many proprietary 8-bit code-pages (mapping bytes to characters) from IBM, DEC, HP, Apple, etc.

> One notable way in which ISO character sets differ from code pages is
> that the character positions 128 to 159, corresponding to ASCII
> control characters with the high-order bit set, are specifically
> unused and undefined in the ISO standards, though they had often been
> used for printable characters in proprietary code pages

i.e. in all the ISO 8-bit extensions, characters 128-159 (`80`-`9F`) are not used, whereas in the previous proprietary code-pages these were used for ASCII control characters (that already exist in 7-bit ascii) but with the 8th bit set.

The above statement about `80`-`9F` not being used/defined is not exactly true.  Apparently in the ISO/IEC standard, this range **is defined** for control characters, but in the IANA character set of the same name, this range **is not defined**.  I got this from some archived discussion on the confusingly written and misleading wikipedia page for windows-1252...but was unable to verify as the ISO standards are paywalled.

### windows-1252

...to further confuse things.

After the ISO 8-bit extensions came out, Microsoft released a new code-page `windows-1252` which is a **superset*** of `ISO-8859-1` that uses the unused ISO range of characters 128-159 (`80`-`9F`) for things like smart quotes.  Compare rows 8x and 9x of the code tables ([iso-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Code_page_layout) [windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Codepage_layout)) if you don't understand.

Superset means that if you render `ISO-8859-1` as `windows-1252` it looks fine (because all printable characters in `ISO-8859-1` also exist in `windows-1252` with the same encoding)...but if you try to render `windows-1252` as `ISO-8859-1` and the rendered data happens to contain bytes in the 128-159 range, then those characters won't display properly.

> It is very common to mislabel Windows-1252 text with the charset label
> ISO-8859-1. A common result was that all the quotes and apostrophes
> (produced by "smart quotes" in word-processing software) were replaced
> with question marks or boxes on non-Windows operating systems, making
> text difficult to read. Most modern web browsers and e-mail clients
> treat the media type charset ISO-8859-1 as Windows-1252 to accommodate
> such mislabeling. This is now standard behavior in the HTML5
> specification, which requires that documents advertised as ISO-8859-1
> actually be parsed with the Windows-1252 encoding.

So in the html5 standard, there is no encoding named `ISO-8859-1`, instead `iso-8859-1` is one of multiple labels for encoding `windows-1252`.

[windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252#Details)

[html5 encodings](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-windows-1252%E2%91%A0)

`*` - note, not technically a superset of the ISO/IEC 8859-1 standard, because the standard defines control characters in the `80`-`9F` range and `windows-1252` defines different characters in this range.  But the IANA characterset 8859-1 does NOT define characters in this range, so technically it is a superset of the IANA characterset but not the ISO/IEC standard?  (This is why standards should be open, so we can check these things.)

### Detecting encoding with `file`

One lesson I learned today is that we can't trust `file` to always give correct interpretation of a file's character encoding.

*[file (command)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29)*

> The command tells only what the file looks like, not what it is (in the case where file looks at the content). It is easy to fool the program by putting a magic number into a file the content of which does not match it. Thus the command is not usable as a security tool other than in specific situations.

`file` looks for magic numbers in the file that hint at the type, but these can be wrong, no guarantee of correctness. `file` also tries to guess the character encoding by looking at the bytes in the file. Basically `file` has a series of tests that helps it guess at the file type and encoding.

My file is a large CSV file. `file` reports this file as US ASCII encoded, which is **WRONG**.

```
$ ls -lh
total 850832
-rw-r--r--  1 mattp  staff   415M Mar 14 16:38 source-file
$ file -b --mime-type source-file
text/plain
$ file -b --mime-encoding source-file
us-ascii
```

My file has umlauts in it (ie Ö). The first non-7-bit-ascii doesn't show up until over 100k lines into the file. I suspect this is why `file` doesn't realize the file encoding isn't US-ASCII.

```
$ pcregrep -no '[^\x00-\x7F]' source-file | head -n1
102321:�
```

I'm on a Mac, so using [PCRE's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) `grep`. With GNU grep you could use the `-P` option. Alternatively on a Mac, one could install [coreutils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) (via [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_%28package_management_software%29) or other) in order to get GNU grep.

I haven't dug into the source-code of `file`, and the man page doesn't discuss the text encoding detection in detail, but I am guessing `file` doesn't look at the whole file before guessing encoding.

Whatever my file's encoding is, these non-7-bit-ASCII characters break stuff. My German CSV file is `;`-separated and extracting a single column doesn't work.

```
$ cut -d";" -f1 source-file > tmp
cut: stdin: Illegal byte sequence
$ wc -l *
 3081673 source-file
  102320 tmp
 3183993 total
```

Note the `cut` error and that my "tmp" file has only 102320 lines with the first special character on line 102321.

Let's take a look at how these non-ASCII characters are encoded. I dump the first non-7-bit-ascii into `hexdump`, do a little formatting, remove the newlines (`0a`) and take just the first few.

```
$ pcregrep -o '[^\x00-\x7F]' source-file | head -n1 | hexdump -v -e '1/1 "%02x\n"'
d6
0a
```

Another way. I know the first non-7-bit-ASCII char is at position 85 on line 102321. I grab that line and tell `hexdump` to take the two bytes starting at position 85.  You can see the special (non-7-bit-ASCII) character represented by a ".", and the next byte is "M"... so this is a single-byte character encoding.

```
$ tail -n +102321 source-file | head -n1 | hexdump -C -s85 -n2
00000055  d6 4d                                             |.M|
00000057
```

In both cases, we see the special character is represented by `d6`. Since this character is an Ö which is a German letter, I am guessing that ISO 8859-1 should include this. Sure enough, you can see "d6" is a match (*[ISO/IEC 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout)*).

Important question... how do I know this character is an Ö without being sure of the file encoding? The answer is context. I opened the file, read the text and then determined what character it is supposed to be. If I open it in [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) it displays as an Ö because Vim does a better job of *guessing* the character encoding (in this case) than `file` does.

So, my file seems to be ISO 8859-1. In theory I should check the rest of the non-7-bit-ASCII characters to make sure ISO 8859-1 is a good fit... There is nothing that forces a program to only use a single encoding when writing a file to disk (other than good manners).

I'll skip the check and move on to conversion step.

```
$ iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 source-file > output-file
$ file -b --mime-encoding output-file
us-ascii
```

Hmm. `file` still tells me this file is US ASCII even after conversion. Let's check with `hexdump` again.

```
$ tail -n +102321 output-file | head -n1 | hexdump -C -s85 -n2
00000055  c3 96                                             |..|
00000057
```

Definitely a change. Note that we have two bytes of non-7-bit-ASCII (represented by the "." on the right) and the hex code for the two bytes is now `c3 96`. If we take a look, seems we have UTF-8 now (`c3 96` is the encoding of `Ö` in UTF-8)  *[UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)*

But `file` still reports our file as `us-ascii`? Well, I think this goes back to the point about `file` not looking at the whole file and the fact that the first non-7-bit-ASCII characters don't occur until late in the file.

I'll use `sed` to stick a Ö at the beginning of the file and see what happens.

```
$ sed '1s/^/Ö\'$'\n/' source-file > test-file
$ head -n1 test-file
Ö
$ head -n1 test-file | hexdump -C
00000000  c3 96 0a                                          |...|
00000003
```

Cool, we have an umlaut. Note the encoding though is `c3 96` (UTF-8). Hmm.

Checking our other umlauts in the same file again:

```
$ tail -n +102322 test-file | head -n1 | hexdump -C -s85 -n2
00000055  d6 4d                                             |.M|
00000057
```

ISO 8859-1. Oops! It just goes to show how easy it is to get the encodings screwed up.  To be clear, I've managed to create a mix of UTF-8 and ISO 8859-1 encodings in the same file.

Let's try converting our mangled (mixed encoding) test file with the umlaut (Ö) at the front and see what happens.

```
$ iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 test-file > test-file-converted
$ head -n1 test-file-converted | hexdump -C
00000000  c3 83 c2 96 0a                                    |.....|
00000005
$ tail -n +102322 test-file-converted | head -n1 | hexdump -C -s85 -n2
00000055  c3 96                                             |..|
00000057
```

The first umlaut that was UTF-8 was interpreted as ISO 8859-1 since that is what we told `iconv`...not what we want, but that is what we told iconf to do. The second umlaut is correctly converted from `d6` (ISO 8859-1) to `c3 96` (UTF-8).

I'll try again, but this time I will use Vim to do the Ö insertion instead of `sed`. Vim seemed to detect the encoding better before (as "latin1" aka ISO 8859-1) so perhaps it will insert the new Ö with a consistent encoding.

```
$ vim source-file
$ head -n1 test-file-2
�
$ head -n1 test-file-2 | hexdump -C
00000000  d6 0d 0a                                          |...|
00000003
$ tail -n +102322 test-file-2 | head -n1 | hexdump -C -s85 -n2
00000055  d6 4d                                             |.M|
00000057
```

Indeed vim used the correct/consistent ISO encoding when inserting the character at the beginning of the file.

Now the test:  Does file do a better job of recognizing the encoding with special characters at the beginning of the file?

```
$ file -b --mime-encoding test-file-2
iso-8859-1
$ iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf8 test-file-2 > test-file-2-converted
$ file -b --mime-encoding test-file-2-converted
utf-8
```

Yes it does! Moral of the story. Don't trust `file` to always guess your encoding right. It is easy to mix encodings within the same file. When in doubt, look at the hex.

A hack that would address this specific limitation of `file` when dealing with large files would be to shorten the file to make sure that special (non-ascii) characters appear early in the file so `file` is more likely to find them.

```
$ first_special=$(pcregrep -o1 -n '()[^\x00-\x7F]' source-file | head -n1 | cut -d":" -f1)
$ tail -n +$first_special source-file > /tmp/source-file-shorter
$ file -b --mime-encoding /tmp/source-file-shorter
iso-8859-1
```

You could then use (presumably correct) detected encoding to feed as input to `iconv` to ensure you are converting correctly.

## Update

Christos Zoulas updated `file` to make the amount of bytes looked at configurable. One day turn-around on the feature request, awesome!

http://bugs.gw.com/view.php?id=533
*[Allow altering how many bytes to read from analyzed files from the command line](https://github.com/file/file/commit/d04de269e0b06ccd0a7d1bf4974fed1d75be7d9e)*

The feature was released in `file` version 5.26.

Looking at more of a large file before making a guess about encoding takes time. However, it is nice to have the option for specific use-cases where a better guess may outweigh additional time and I/O.

Use the following option:

```
−P, −−parameter name=value

    Set various parameter limits.

    Name    Default     Explanation
    bytes   1048576     max number of bytes to read from file
```

Something like...

```
file_to_check="myfile"
bytes_to_scan=$(wc -c < $file_to_check)
file -b --mime-encoding -P bytes=$bytes_to_scan $file_to_check
```

... it should do the trick if you want to force `file` to look at the whole file before making a guess. Of course, this only works if you have `file` 5.26 or newer.

### Update 2023-02-06

Thanks [@theprivileges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403434/theprivileges) for pointing out the parameter behaviour has [changed](https://github.com/file/file/commit/f6dfbb86de9b377f4b8f273d54258b787241e7a2) as of `file` 5.44.  There is now an additional `encoding` parameter that specifies how many bytes of the bytes read by `file` should be used for encoding determination.

e.g.

```bash
file_to_check="myfile"
bytes_to_scan=$(wc -c < $file_to_check)
file -b --mime-encoding -P bytes=$bytes_to_scan -P encoding=$bytes_to_scan file_to_check="myfile"
```

**Note!**  It appears with this change, that the bytes of the file used for determining encoding is now capped to a max of 64k.  So for very large files where special characters only occur late in the file, you may need to resort to a different workaround (e.g. moving special characters up in the file for proper detection).

## Forcing `file` to display UTF-8 instead of US-ASCII

Some of the other answers seem to focus on trying to make `file` display UTF-8 even if the file only contains plain 7-bit ascii.  If you think this through you should probably never want to do this.

1. If a file contains only 7-bit ascii but the `file` command is saying the file is UTF-8, that implies that the file contains some characters with UTF-8 specific encoding.  If that isn't really true, it could cause confusion or problems down the line.  If `file` displayed UTF-8 when the file only contained 7-bit ascii characters, this would be a bug in the `file` program.
2. Any software that requires UTF-8 formatted input files should not have any problem consuming plain 7-bit ascii since this is the same on a byte level as UTF-8.  If there is software that is using the `file` command output before accepting a file as input and it won't process the file unless it "sees" UTF-8...well that is pretty bad design.  I would argue this is a bug in that program.

If you absolutely must take a plain 7-bit ascii file and convert it to UTF-8, simply insert a single non-7-bit-ascii character into the file with UTF-8 encoding for that character and you are done.  But I can't imagine a use-case where you would need to do this.  The easiest UTF-8 character to use for this is the Byte Order Mark (*[BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8)*) which is a special non-printing character that hints that the file is non-ascii.  This is probably the best choice because it should not visually impact the file contents as it will generally be ignored.

> Microsoft compilers and interpreters, and many pieces of software on
> Microsoft Windows such as Notepad treat the BOM as a required magic
> number rather than use heuristics. These tools add a BOM when saving
> text as UTF-8, and **cannot interpret UTF-8 unless the BOM is present
> or the file contains only ASCII**.

This is key:

> or the file contains only ASCII

So some tools on windows have trouble reading UTF-8 files unless the BOM character is present.  However this does not affect plain 7-bit ascii only files.  I.e. this is not a reason for forcing plain 7-bit ascii files to be UTF-8 by adding a BOM character.

Here is more discussion about potential pitfalls of using the BOM when not needed (it IS needed for actual UTF-8 files that are consumed by some Microsoft apps).  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13398447/3616686

Nevertheless if you still want to do it, I would be interested in hearing your use case.  Here is how.  In UTF-8 the BOM is represented by hex sequence `0xEF,0xBB,0xBF` and so we can easily add this character to the front of our plain 7-bit ascii file.  By adding a non-7-bit ascii character to the file, the file is no longer only 7-bit ascii.  Note that we have not modified or converted the original 7-bit-ascii content at all.  We have added a single non-7-bit-ascii character to the beginning of the file and so the file is no longer entirely composed of 7-bit-ascii characters.

```
$ printf '\xEF\xBB\xBF' > bom.txt # put a UTF-8 BOM char in new file
$ file bom.txt
bom.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators
$ file plain-ascii.txt  # our pure 7-bit ascii file
plain-ascii.txt: ASCII text
$ cat bom.txt plain-ascii.txt > plain-ascii-with-utf8-bom.txt # put them together into one new file with the BOM first
$ file plain-ascii-with-utf8-bom.txt
plain-ascii-with-utf8-bom.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text
```

Comment: Indeed, `file` only looks at the first few kb of a file to produce its verdict.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I updated my answer to attempt to be more helpful.  ;)

Comment: I added the missing links, though I was not sure if I guessed the last one correctly.

Comment: (Tempted to also fix the [useless `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) but I'll leave it to yourself.)

Comment: Excellent explanation. This should be the top answer. I have the exact scenario that you described here.

Comment: This answer should be the de-facto top result. I found this solution after several searches and pages read. The -P bytes enhancement is key and perfect for what I needed.

Comment: The `chardet` command is a lot more reliable than `file` is, without any additional parameters - it's also a little slower, so it's possible it looks at the whole file by default.

Comment: The parameter to use on `file` is now [`encoding`](https://github.com/file/file/commit/f6dfbb86de9b377f4b8f273d54258b787241e7a2) instead of `bytes`. 

`file -b --mime-encoding -P encoding=$bytes_to_scan $file_to_check`

Answer (score 26):

People say you can't and I understand you may be frustrated when asking a question and getting such an answer.

If you really want it to show in UTF-8 instead of US ASCII then you need to do it in two steps.

First:

```
iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-16 yourfile > youfileinutf16.*
```

Second:

```
iconv -f utf-16le -t utf-8 yourfileinutf16 > yourfileinutf8.*
```

Then if you do a `file -i`, you'll see the new character set is UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you this is just what I needed

Answer (score 14):

I think [Ned's got the core of the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303405/force-encode-from-us-ascii-to-utf-8-iconv/11303410#11303410) -- your files are not actually ASCII. Try

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 file.php > file-utf8.php
```

I'm just guessing that you're actually using [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). It is popular with most European languages.

Comment: Nope. It didn't do the trick.. I've tried it but anyway, if I run `$ file --mime file.php` I get `file.php: text/x-php charset=us-ascii`... So I presume my files are actually ASCII encoded?

Comment: `file` won't inspect an entire file; try moving the strings to the top of the file, perhaps in a comment block.

Comment: Another option to see if you've got an ascii file is to run a script like this Ruby program: `File.open("file.php").each_char {|c| puts c if c.ord > 127}`. (I picked Ruby because I knew how to write this quickly; any other similar language would be similarly easy.)

Comment: According to Smultron my files are Unicode (UTF-8) encoded... So Ned is right indeed. US-ASCII is a subset of UTF-8. Then my problem should come from something else (thing is I am not dealing with the non-ASCII strings inside the php file BUT am receiving them over the internet: I'm scraping a webpage...). Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between US ASCII and UTF-8, so there isn't any need to reconvert it.

But here a little hint, if you have trouble with special-chars while recoding.

Add //TRANSLIT after the source-charset-Parameter.

**Example:**

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT -t UTF-8 filename.sql > utf8-filename.sql
```

This helps me with strange types of quotes, which are always breaking the character set reencode process.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a script that will find all files matching a pattern you pass it, and then converting them from their current file encoding to UTF-8. If the encoding is US ASCII, then it will still show as US ASCII, since that is a subset of UTF-8.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find . -name "${1}" |
    while read line;
    do
        echo "***************************"
        echo "Converting ${line}"

        encoding=$(file -b --mime-encoding ${line})
        echo "Found Encoding: ${encoding}"

        iconv -f "${encoding}" -t "utf-8" ${line} -o ${line}.tmp
        mv ${line}.tmp ${line}
    done
```

Answer (score 2):

```
vim -es '+set fileencoding=utf-8' '+wq!' file
```

`-es` runs vim in `ex` and `script` mode, thus nothing is rendered. Then it executes the command where the file encoding is set (vim takes care of the details) and then the file is closed '+wq!'.

I am late to the question but the previous answers using `iconv` did simply not do the job and left the file in a state with non utf-8 characters even when adding `-c` to drop those.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `file -i file_name` to check what exactly your original file format is.

Once you get that, you can do the following:

```
iconv -f old_format -t utf-8 input_file -o output_file
```

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally encoded a file in UTF-7 and had a similar issue. When I typed  `file -i name.file` I would get `charset=us-ascii`.

`iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-9//translit name.file` would not work since I've gathered UTF-7 is a subset of US ASCII, as is UTF-8.

To solve this, I entered

`iconv -f UTF-7 -t UTF-8//TRANSLIT name.file -o output.file`

I'm not sure how to determine the encoding other than what others have suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

The following converts all files in a folder.

**Create backup folder of original files**.

```
mkdir backup
```

**Convert all files in US ASCII encoding to UTF-8 (single line command)**

```
for f in $(file -i * .sql | grep us-ascii | cut -d ':' -f 1); do iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 $f -o $ f.utf-8 && mv $f backup / && mv "$f.utf-8" $f; done
```

**Convert all files in encoding ISO 8859-1 to UTF-8 (single line command)**

```
for f $(file -i * .sql | grep iso-8859-1 | cut -d ':' -f 1); do iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 $f -o $f.utf-8 && mv $f backup / && mv "$f.utf-8" $f; done
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired a lot by [Mathieu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303405/force-encode-from-us-ascii-to-utf-8-iconv/36149803#36149803) and [Marcelo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303405/force-encode-from-us-ascii-to-utf-8-iconv/59628912#59628912):

I face the need to see `file -i myfile.htm` to show UTF-8 instead of US ASCII (yes, I know it is a subset of UTF-8).

So here is a one liner inspired from previous answers that will convert on Linux all *.htm file from US ASCII to UTF-8 so `file -i` will show you UTF-8. You can change *.htm (two places in the command below) to fit your need.

```
mkdir backup 2>/dev/null; for f in $(file -i *.htm | grep -i us-ascii | cut -d ':' -f 1); do iconv -f "us-ascii" -t "utf-16" $f > $f.tmp; iconv -f "utf-16le" -t "utf-8" $f.tmp > $f.utf8; cp $fic backup/; mv $f.utf8 $f; rm $f.tmp; done; file -i *.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, `file` doesn't check whole content (as already mentioned in the long answer from [mattpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303405/force-encode-from-us-ascii-to-utf-8-iconv/36030982#36030982)) to detect encoding of a file by default. To force the whole content to be scanned for charset detection, this code can be used...

```
file_to_check="myfile"
bytes_to_scan=$(wc -c < $file_to_check)
file -b --mime-encoding --parameter encoding=$bytes_to_scan $file_to_check
```

See also corresponding manual https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html