# Loading of file having non-printable UTF-8 characters to apache-hive table showing junk characters/boxes � �

Tags: java, linux, utf-8, hive, file-format

When I'm trying to load a file to Hive, some of the characters are not getting interpreted properly and are coming up as boxes in hive.

[image: Data in hive]

Using the "`file`" command, I get the file type as below:

```
ksh> file -bi data.TXT
text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Below is a data sample (opened in vim editor in a Putty terminal linux machine having Settings: Window>Translation>Remote character Set as UTF-8):

```
338498281INT057575238000ZENECA 176334                                                          9
338498282INT015250238000<8d>4CYANO3(TRIFLUOROMETHYL)PHENYLÙ3<8d>4FLUOROPHENYL)SULFONYLHYDROXYMETHPRO 9
```

Below is a snapshot of the same (Notice the Blue color of <8d> character in 2nd row, which I want to remove, and keep the `Ù` : U with Gravel )

[image: Data Sample]
I've tried removing it using `sed, tr` commands, but still the data comes as boxes.

```
cat data.TXT | tr -d '\215'  > data_tr_215.TXT  # Ù still coming as boxes in hive
```

I've also tried to convert it using Java's [InputStreamReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader(java.io.InputStream,%20java.lang.String)) and [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html#OutputStreamWriter(java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.String)) , but even that gives the result as boxes : `000�4CYANO3(TRIFLUOROMETHYL)PHENYL�3�4FLUOROPHENYL)`

```
scala> val fsDataInputStream = hdfs.open(new Path("data.TXT"))
fsDataInputStream: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream = org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.HdfsDataInputStream@7789f96c: org.apache.hadoop.crypto.CryptoInputStream@b274834

scala> val isr = new InputStreamReader(fsDataInputStream)
isr: java.io.InputStreamReader = java.io.InputStreamReader@4e8b0758

scala> isr.getEncoding
res1: String = UTF8
```

How can I get rid of these charactes and still load the data properly having  `Ù` ?

Comment: it seems that it isn't really US-ASCII format https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303405/force-encode-from-us-ascii-to-utf-8-iconv  it's just an educated guess.
What is the source of your input files?

Comment: The presence of `<8d>` means your file is neither UTF-8 nor ASCII.  Try the `"windows-1252"` encoding.

Comment: @Tschallacka Yes, it looks like it's not really 7-bit us-ascii as it says. It looks more like ISO-8859-1.
mattpr 's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36030982/4604453 helped to identify it better. Trying out the solution.