# Convert encoded characters into normal [A-Z] characters

Tags: php, xml, encoding, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to transliterate accented characters into plain ASCII characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542717/how-to-transliterate-accented-characters-into-plain-ascii-characters)

I have a problem with encoding in PHP, for example i want

`Orléans` to be transformed in `Orleans`

`Angoulême` to `Angouleme`

`Ň` to `N`

... and so on see the table here

`http://www.thesauruslex.com/typo/eng/enghtml.htm`

Is there a solution to this? And also when the script encounter a non [A-Z] character to make it XML ENTITY.

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think that this is a good idea, ever?

Comment: This looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: i know is just running from the enemy, but i want to make sure that i have only A-Z chars

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php will help

Comment: @justderb `Notice: iconv() [function.iconv]: Detected an illegal character in input string in` .. why?

Comment: Because you have an illegal character! See the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 1):

Possibly use: `iconv('utf-8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);`

More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 1):

```
  $str1 = 'Orléans'
  $str2 = 'Angoulême'
  $rule = 'NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC';

  $transliter = Transliterator::create($rule); 
  echo $transliter->transliterate($str1);
  echo $transliter->transliterate($str2);
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Class 'Transliterator' not found` ... do i really need this class?

Comment: @RowMinds: You need the extension: [PHP Internationalization Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.intl.php)

Answer (score -3):

```
$unwanted_array = array('Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U','Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u','ü'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );


// TESTING
$str1 = 'Orléans';
$str2 = 'Angoulême';
echo strtr($str1,$unwanted_array);
```

This is what i needed, why is working so well, yet is so simple ?