# foreign characters not showing PHP

Tags: php

I have a column in a database called `Name` I'm doing an **echo()** on this column to show the value (simple knowledge)

When doing an **var_dump** on the mySQL row, I'm shown the following

```
["Name"]=> string(10) "Marko Baša"
```

If I go ahead and do `echo $Name` I'm shown the following

```
Marko Baa
```

But then, If I go ahead and do a `utf8_encode` arround it, it appears a little better

```
Marko BaÂša
```

How could I get it to display like so

```
Marko Basa
```

Comment: If you're looking to replace `š` with `s`, then you're looking for [transliteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13614622/transliterate-any-convertible-utf8-char-into-ascii-equivalent)

Comment: `š` and `s` are different characters - I'm thinking you just need to use `str_replace`.

Comment: check http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php will help you out

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove accents and turn letters into "plain" ASCII characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542717/how-to-remove-accents-and-turn-letters-into-plain-ascii-characters)

Comment: There are several questions on this topic, but the question I just linked to seems to have the best answers of the ones I've found (despite being marked as a duplicate itself).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `iconv` to transliterate:

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', 'Marko Baša');
```

Comment: When using that, it doesn't display anything?

Comment: Replace `UTF-8` with your actual charset?  It works for me, but my scripts are actually saved in UTF-8.  Alternately, you could `utf8_encode` the string before passing it to `iconv` (looking at the documentation, it seems that converts from `ISO-8859-1`).

Answer (score 1):

Set your charset in the HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

The browser is apparently not interpreting your page as UTF-8 by default.

Comment: This is directly from PHP (a script), with no HTML parsing

Comment: On the command line?  Whoops - didn't notice the missing accent on the last example...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: @KateGregory It works for essentially the same reason as `<meta charset="UTF-8">` - and fails to answer this question for exactly the same reason.