# Replace unicode characters in PHP with their ascii equivinant

Tags: php, unicode, ascii

How can I replace non-traditional unicode characters in PHP? For example:

```
Jose França
```

Should be replaced to:

```
Jose Franca
```

Comment: You cannot simply replace them.  is ß a B or is a ss?  The point of unicode is that it is a larger set of characters without direct equivalencies.  Create the mapping yourself and enforce it if you have to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814547/converting-unicode-characters-into-the-equivalent-ascii-ones

Comment: For that matter: What is the "ASCII equivalent" of ✀? Or 中?