# Why two words don't match when they're the same?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have to compare two words. The first word is "módulo" and the other one is "modulo". I've tried to replace the accent, then I realize the word never changed after call the method to replace the accent. 
I get the first word from two arrays. The first array from an unserialize array called **tipo**.

```
<? 
$tipo = unserialize(TIPO); 
$estado = unserialize(ESTADO);  ?>
```

The second array comes from a database result, **$prop['propiedad_tipo']**  **propiedad_tipo** is int type.

```
$tipo_dato = (@$prop['propiedad_tipo'])?$tipo[ $prop['propiedad_tipo'] ]:'';
```

Through this value I can access to an index from "**tipo**" array, this is where i get the word "módulo".

And when I do this

```
if($tipo_dato == 'módulo')
  $tipo_dato = 'modulo';
```

nothing happens :( please help.

Ps. sorry for my english :(

--
Maybe this helps

```
$tipo_dato = (@$prop['propiedad_tipo'])?strtolower($tipo[ $prop['propiedad_tipo'] ]):''; 
  echo serialize($tipo_dato); echo '<br>'.serialize('módulo');
```

The result is s:13:"módulo"; s:7:"módulo";

--
I've found the big error. When i serialized the array "TIPO" I used   `m&oacute;dulo`  I chaged it to módulo and then everything works fine...
Thank you so much for your help

Comment: What character sets are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this which looks quite useful for what you need:

```
function toASCII( $str )
{
    return strtr(utf8_decode($str), 
        utf8_decode(
        'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ'),
        'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy');
}
```

Taken from [How to remove accents and turn letters into "plain" ASCII characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542717/how-to-transliterate-accented-characters-into-plain-ascii-characters)

Then you can use:

```
$tipo_dato = toASCII($tipo_dato);
```

Comment: I did this and still return the word with the accent :(

Comment: I copied the módulo word into a test php file and it worked for me there so I am guessing that the reason your IF is not working is that it is not the same ASCII character

Comment: When i serialized the array "TIPO" I used   `m&oacute;dulo`   I chaged it to módulo and then everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

using

```
if($tipo_dato=='modulo')
    $tipo_dato='modulo';
```

makes no sense. It checks if the value is modulo, and then assigns modulo. Change it to

```
if($tipo_dato!='modulo')
    $tipo_dato='modulo';
```

or change it to

```
if($tipo_dato=='modulo')
     #do some other thing
```

Comment: thanks for answer but if you see again I compare modulo with módulo, with accent, if this is true i change it to modulo.

Comment: i need to change  **módulo**  to  **modulo**

Answer (score 0):

Its may be issue in value retreiving the  through database sotry to find what value $tipo_dato get through database

```
   $tipo_dato = (@$prop['propiedad_tipo'])?$tipo[ $prop['propiedad_tipo'] ]:''; 
     echo "$tipo_dato";
```

I think its just the swaping concept where one method to try this simple code.

```
//initial check the value 
echo "$uid<br>";
echo "$bid";

//after the swaping the value 
$d=$uid;
$uid="$bid";
$bid="$d";

//final outcome
echo "$uid<br>";
 echo "$bid";

  ?>
```