# Url Romanization Issues

Tags: php, character-replacement, xenforo

I am using Xenforo forum script. for non english character on threads title, there is a function converting non english character to english character.

whenever I post "ö" is converting to "oe". but functions array is;

```
$title = strtr($title, array(
    '"' => '',
    "'" => '',
    "Ö" => "o",
    "ö" => "o",
    "C" => "c",
    "c" => "c",
    "Ğ" => "g",
    "ğ" => "g",
    "Ş" => "s",
    "ş" => "s",
    "Ü" => "u",
    "ü" => "u",
    "İ" => "i",
    "ı" => "i",
    "Ç" => "c",
    "ç" => "c",
    "é" => "i",
    "â" => "a",
    "Ê" => "e",
    "Â" => "a",
    "?" => "_",
    "*" => "_",
    "." => "_",
    "," => "_",
    ";" => "_",
    ")" => "_",
    "(" => "_",
    "{" => "_",
    "}" => "_",
    "[" => "_",
    "]" => "_",
    "!" => "_",
    "+" => "_",
    "%" => "_",
    "&" => "_",
    "#" => "_",
    "$" => "_",
    "=" => "_",
    "ê" => "e",
    "." => "-"
    ));
```

why "ö" character is converting to "oe"? I wanna "ö" as "o".

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why "ö" is not converting according to array? I wanna "ö" as "o".

Comment: THen you should give more information: what language do you use (PHP?), is the code part of a framework, what does your code look like? It is hard to say what's going wrong without that.

Comment: xenforo is based on php.

Comment: You are missing roughly 10000 other characters that would need transliteration. Go for a more general approach like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542717/how-to-transliterate-accented-characters-into-plain-ascii-characters

Comment: as Robert stated in his answer, use that to replace "ö" with "o" and then call your your function

Answer (score 1):

You can use your own replacement for certain characters:

```
$title = str_replace("ö","o",$title);
```

In this case you should comment out the code that you have posted so that

> ö

is not changed into

> oe

before your replacing function gets called.

Comment: I wanna changing "ö" to "o", but it can't.

Answer (score 0):

I found other file about romanization.... there is UTF-8 Case lookup table file.