# Iterating through XML file with php

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file with the following:

```
<property>
  <id>1</id>
  <type>type</type>
  <town>town</town>
  <province>province</province>
  <images>
    <image id="1">
    <url>
      http://www.test.com
    </url>
    <image id="2">
    <url>
      http://www.test.com
    </url>
    <image id="3">
    <url>
      http://www.test.com
    </url>
  </image>
```

I can iterate through the file and get the value except the image url.
I am struggling with the element after the element with an attribute.

```
$count=0;
$id=0;
foreach($xml->children() as $properties) {
    echo "<h1>" . $xml->property[$count]->type . " for sale in " .$xml->property[$count]->town . ", " . $xml->property[$count]->province . "</h1>" . "<br>";
    echo $xml->property[$count]->id . "<br>";
    echo $xml->property[$count]->desc->en . "<br>";

    foreach($xml->property[$count]->children() as $images) {
        echo $xml->property[$count]->images -> image[$id++] -> url;
        $id++;
}
    $count++;
}
```

but the 2nd loop isn´t close to being right.
I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: whats the end result you want?

Comment: my apologies, it would help! I want to display each image. I just need the code that returns the value of <url> for images -> image [id..] -> url .

Comment: I don't know the correct xml terminology but each <property> element contains a <images> element with <images> a sub element <image id = "1..8"> and that as a <url> element. I want the url of each image.
<image id="1">
<url>
http://
</url>
</image>
<image id="2">
<url>
http://</url>
</image>
<image id="3">
<url>
http://</url>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shared the complete XML structure so it's unclear where the root of the document is (the document element).

Assuming that the root element is not `<property>` but all `<property>` elements are children of the root element you can iterate over all those `<property>` elements by simply just iterating over them:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('example.xml');

foreach ($xml->property as $property) {
    printf(
        "<h1>%s for sale in %s, %s</h1>\n", htmlspecialchars($property->id), 
        htmlspecialchars($property->town), htmlspecialchars($property->province)
    );
```

As you can see, you don't need to make use of a `$count` variable explicitly. You can, but you don't need to. Just saying.

Now you're looking for the image URLs. Each `<property>` element has a single child element named `<images>` and these again have mulitple `<url>` elements you're interested in.

This can be done with an xpath query (as you go down deeper more than one level):

```
$urls = $property->xpath('images/image/url');
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    printf(" - %s\n", htmlspecialchars(trim($url)));
}
```

If you don't use xpath here, you would have needed to make a foreach for every single level that contains more than a single child. Just as a counter-example:

```
foreach ($property->images->image as $image) {
    foreach ($image->url as $url) {
        printf(" - %s\n", htmlspecialchars(trim($url)));
    }
}
```

I hope this shows you more well how the traversal works in simplexml. There is some more great material in the PHP manual entitled [Basic SimpleXML usage](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) which shows basic traversal and also links to the more advanced xpath topic.

And don't forget when you output dynamic data into HTML to properly HTML encode it. I've used the [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function for that, you need to provide the correct encoding parameters which I've left out for brevity in my answer.

Example in full:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929239/iterating-through-xml-file-with-php
 */

$buffer = <<<XML
<root>
    <property>
        <id>1</id>
        <type>type</type>
        <town>town</town>
        <province>province</province>
        <images>
            <image id="1">
                <url>
                    http://www.test.com
                </url>
            </image>
            <image id="2">
                <url>
                    http://www.test.com
                </url>
            </image>
            <image id="3">
                <url>
                    http://www.test.com
                </url>
            </image>
        </images>
    </property>
    <property>
        <id>1</id>
        <images>
            <image id="1">
                <url>
                    http://www.test.com
                </url>
            </image>
         </images>
    </property>
</root>
XML;


$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

foreach ($xml->property as $property) {
    printf(
        "<h1>%s for sale in %s, %s</h1>\n",
        htmlspecialchars($property->id), htmlspecialchars($property->town), htmlspecialchars($property->province)
    );

    $urls = $property->xpath('images/image/url');
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        printf(" - %s\n", htmlspecialchars(trim($url)));
    }
}
```

Exemplary output (plain-text):

```
<h1>1 for sale in town, province</h1>
 - http://www.test.com
 - http://www.test.com
 - http://www.test.com
<h1>1 for sale in , </h1>
 - http://www.test.com
```

## Transliteration and Output Encoding with SimpleXML

One way to globally apply transliteration (removal of accents) and HTML encoding (`htmlspecialchars`) for every string-value of the **SimpleXMLElement** can be achieved by extending it. There is a shortcomming: a **SimpleXMLElement** can't have private properties (because the properties are all magic), however you can create static global variables. For keeping the instance of a [**Transliterator**](http://php.net/transliterator) this is enough. And for manipulating the string values, the [`__toString()` magic method](http://php.net/language.oop5.magic#object.tostring) works well with **SimpleXMLElement**:

```
/**
 * Transliterate and HTML encode
 *
 * Class XMLTransliterated
 */
class XMLTransliterated extends SimpleXMLElement
{
    public static $transliterator;

    public function __toString()
    {
        $transliterator = &self::$transliterator;
        $transliterator || $transliterator = Transliterator::create("Latin-ASCII");

        $transliterated = $transliterator->transliterate($this);

        return htmlspecialchars(trim($transliterated), ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
    }
}
```

All you need to do to benefit from the string manipulations is to either use this classname `XMLTransliterated` (or whichever you would name the class) when creating the **SimpleXMLElement**:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer, 'XMLTransliterated');
```

- or - and this is very special to simplexml, you can change the class later on with a little conversion trick:

```
$xml = simplexml_import_dom(dom_import_simplexml($xml), 'XMLTransliterated');
```

This will make the following code use an **XMLTransliterated** instead of the previous less specific **SimpleXMLElement** so the code largely remains the same (please note that the `htmlspecialchars` and `trim` calls could be safely removed as they are now automatically called when accessing the string-values of the **SimpleXMLElement**):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer, 'XMLTransliterated');

foreach ($xml->property as $property) {
    printf(
        "<h1>%s (%s) for sale in %s, %s</h1>\n",
        $property->id, $property->type, $property->town, $property->province
    );

    $urls = $property->xpath('images/image/url');
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        printf(" - %s\n", $url);
    }
}
```

But the output will turn "`Schloß`" into "`schloss`", "`tôwn`" into "`town`" and "`provincé`" into "`province`".

**Transliterator** requires PHP 5.4 and you having the [Intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) enabled (which you should have, if not enable it).

Alternatively you can also make use of [transliteration from the iconv library](http://php.net/iconv). But beware, this produces slightly different output:

```
$transliterated = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $this);
```

More related transliteration questions:

- [PHP: Replace umlauts with closest 7-bit ASCII equivalent in an UTF-8 string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/158241/367456) (Oct 2008)
- [How to remove accents and turn letters into “plain” ASCII characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3542717/367456) (Aug 2010)

Comment: many thanks this works. I tried to add a comment but couldn't. I've also tried to mark it as correct.

Comment: The encoding part is difficult for me. Do you happen to know how I can change special characters like ó and á as "o" and "a" or if not, at least display them correctly.  $output = "property_for_sale_in_" . $property->town. "_" . $property->province."_".$count.".html"; I tried with various methods including headers and not succeeded.

Comment: I've managed to ó to display as ó using charset=ISO-8859-1 but can't manage to format ó as o.

Comment: @sharon: What is the character encoding of the output you create?

Comment: Thanks again for your help hakre. To finalize the thread for others who come across it, I have settled for using utf-8 and then formatting with a replacement function $prop_province = removeAccents($property->province); that I found here http://www.pontikis.net/tip/?id=22 . I couldn't find any other fail safe method.

Comment: @sharon: Use `strtr` of `str_replace` for that function, also make the translation array static. However what you're looking for is called *transliteration* I'll update the answer with an example. Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: @sharon: Extended the answer with an example on how to transparently transliterate and html-encode the values a SimpleXMLElement provides by extending from it and changing the behavior of `__toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
foreach($xml->property[$count]->images as $image) {
    echo $image->url;
}
```