# How to fully replace all special characters in PHP without leaving any HTML Entity in the result

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace, html-entities

I need help with a PHP replace function I am trying to create.

Basically, I want to FYLLY convert all special characters like `á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, Á, É, Í, Ó, Ú, Ü, Ñ` and so on to this:  `a, e, i, o, u, u, n, A, E, I, O, U, U, N`. Below is explained why I say "FULLY convert".

Now I have only managed to do this half way using the below function:

```
function clean_url($text){
         $text = preg_replace('~&([a-z]{1,10})(acute|cedil|circ|grave|lig|orn|ring|slash|th|tilde|uml);~i', '$1', htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
    return $text;
}
```

This at first glance gives me the desired result when viewed in MySQL or a browser, so in PHP:

```
$string = "Ábalos";
echo clean_url($string);
```

HTML Page source code output: `Abalos`. This look about right at first glance.

But when I do

```
$string = "Ábalos";
echo htmlentities(clean_url(($string));
```

HTML Page source code output: `A&Acirc;?balos`.

I want to be able to replace with my function also that part `&Acirc;?`. 
How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this function (in this thread : [How to remove accents and turn letters into "plain" ASCII characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542717/how-to-remove-accents-and-turn-letters-into-plain-ascii-characters)) :

```
function toASCII( $str )
{
    return strtr(utf8_decode($str), 
        utf8_decode(
        'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ'),
        'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy');
}
```

I tested some strings and it works. For example :

```
function toASCII( $str )
{
    return strtr(utf8_decode($str), 
        utf8_decode(
        'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ'),
        'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeiiiionoooooouuuuyy');
}

$string = "Ábalos";

echo toASCII($string);
```

will print `Abalos`

Comment: Well, in my case it prints `A?balos`. Any ideas why?

Comment: In your php.ini file verify that `default_charset` is set to UTF-8 like this `default_charset = "utf-8"`

Answer (score 2):

you can use `iconv` to accomplish this.

```
<?php

    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8');

    $str = "Ábalos";

    echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);

?>
```

Comment: I tried that but it leaves me with `A balos`. And I cannot replace the space because it can be an actual space.

Comment: @user3132858 that's odd I don't see a space when I run it.

Comment: Not sure what I did (since I am stuggling with it for 10 hours now) but now it shows `A?balos`. What can be the issue now?