# PHP str_replace doesnt replace character "°"

Tags: php, string, phpexcel

**Hello !**

I am getting a String from a .xlsx file ->`"N°X"`

I would like to replace `"N°"` by `Num_X`

I am trying to do this with

```
$var = str_replace("N°","Num_",$var);
```

But nothing is replaced (according to `echo $var`)
  problem come from `°` because when i try to replace some String by other 
  (without `°`) str_replace works

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It's probably not the same character you're replacing, but a character that looks similar.

Comment: try mb_str_replace, but it works on local. It must be a difference character than what you think it is

Comment: @Ice76 I tried on local machine as well, seems to work fine.

Comment: Can't seem to replicate! Are you using PHP7?

Comment: It's possible that the PHP file (on-disk) is not encoded in UTF-8 and `str_replace()` is probably set to UTF-8

Comment: Works fine at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: Could be useful, https://stackoverflow.com/q/3587383/2191572

Comment: Are you sure it's not `&deg;` or `&#176;`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that input string is UTF8.

```
$var = "N°X";
print mb_detect_encoding($var);
```

If you don't get `UTF-8` out of this, convert it:

```
$var = mb_convert_encoding($var, 'UTF-8');
```

And then your `str_replace` will work as intended.

Another tool that might help you with encoding issues is `xxd`.

```
php -r '$var = "N°X"; echo $var;' | xxd
```

should return

```
00000000: 4ec2 b058                                N..X
```

which reveals the middle character is encoded as C2B0 hex, which is 
Unicode Character 'DEGREE SIGN' (U+00B0). [fileformat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm) comes handy now.

Comment: Also beware of unicode [NUMERO SIGN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2116/index.htm) character (№).

Comment: Oops thought i would get some notifications if i get some answers 

Yes that's what i did $var = mb_convert_encoding ($var,"Windows-1252", "UTF-8"); and it works :)

Thanks