# How can I convert foreign characters to english characters using PHP?

Tags: php

How would I go about converting foreign characters to english characters?

Comment: Please add some more detail and examples. What is a "foreign character"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove accents without using iconv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542818/remove-accents-without-using-iconv)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1284535/php-transliteration

Answer (score 2):

Mapping them:

```
$map = array(
    'á' => 'a',
    'e' => 'e',
// ...
);

$text = str_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP has strtr() that can achieve this. Read more [here](http://php.net/strtr)

The first entry under User Contributed Notes has something that should help you

Answer (score 0):

create an character mapping array with element format: foreign characters => english characters
and replace string with all array element.