# Why doesn't translit work?

Tags: php, iconv

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
$string= 'ṃỹṛèşưḿĕ';
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
```

makes error...

should print: myresume

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the iconv library.

In Ubuntu 10.10, I get this:

```
$ php -i | egrep "iconv (implementation|library)"
iconv implementation => glibc
iconv library version => 2.12.1
$ php a.php 
myresume
```

But on another machine using the GNU iconv:

```
iconv implementation => libiconv
iconv library version => 1.11
# php a.php 
Notice: iconv(): Unknown error (88) in /tmp/root/a.php on line 5
```

The transliteration done by iconv is not consistent across implementations. For instance, the glibc implementation transliterates `é` into `e`, but libiconv transliterates it into `'e`.

Until we have support for ICU transliterators in PHP (due for the next version), there won't be a realiable way to reliable do these transformation (though if you only want to remove marks, there are [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542818/remove-accents-without-using-iconv/3542866#3542866)). In the development version of PHP, with the intl extension, it's possible to do this:

```
<?php
$t = Transliterator::create("latin; NFKD; [^\u0000-\u007E] Remove; NFC");
echo $t->transliterate('Ναδάλης ṃỹṛèşưḿĕ');
```

which gives

```
Nadales myresume
```