# How insert or get O isntead of Ö

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a little website for my mother in php, using mysql.
I want to use the inserted cities to spit out Google Maps.

Problem is that if you insert a city with a Swedish name, such as Norrköping, Google won't give you a map. You have to insert "Norrkoping" without the umlauts.

Is there a way I can change the charset with getting the info, or inputting it, so the dots are removed?

Same thing får Åå (store as Aa) and Ää (store as Aa).

Thanks!

Comment: i was just able to search `Norrköping` on google maps and it worked fine

Comment: A quick SO search turned this up:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158241/php-replace-umlauts-with-closest-7-bit-ascii-equivalent-in-an-utf-8-string)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove accents without using iconv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542818/remove-accents-without-using-iconv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
$s = array('Å', 'å', 'Ö', 'ö');
$r = array('A', 'a', 'O', 'o');
$name = str_replace($s, $r, $name);
```

Translating "svensk-o" to "a" is not really all that much correct, I guess... but it's what you need to make it work, right? You would of course need to add a few more characters if Nürnberg or Crécy are supposed to be un-accented too, but the number of umlauts is very limited, luckily... :-)

Comment: Alright, tried all three from top, and the last one is the one that works! Thanks Damon!!!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [iconv method.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php)

```
echo iconv("utf-8","ascii//TRANSLIT","Norrköping");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($string), "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $string);
echo $string;
```