# Language Special Characters in database search

Tags: php, zend-framework, utf-8, multilingual

me working on search in a multilingual site (currently only english and turkish).

As long as visitor uses the correct language characters, search out puts corrent results.

e.g.

- for word "Moudle" (english) like clause of sql query is like "%Moudle%" and it works fine.
- for word "modül" (turkish) like clause of sql is like "%modül%" and it works fine.

My problem is that for turkish if i use "modul" rather that "modül", it does not works. Only because of "ü".

**Is there any way that i can get results from database even if i use same counterpart characters from english language instead of original?**

---

Structure of table is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS post_lang (
  id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  post_id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  ln enum('en','tr') NOT NULL,
  title text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
INSERT INTO post_lang (id, post_id, ln, title, content, doc) VALUES
(1, 1, 'en', 'How can I create a new module?'),
(2, 1, 'tr', 'NasÄ±l yeni bir modül yaratÄ±rÄ±m?');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a field say `normalizedText` where you are going to store only the chars without accents following your logics.

So you can run a search on your normalizedText with a string not containing accents and having consisent result.

You can use a handy php wordpress function ([remove_accents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542850/496223)) that converts your accented chars to non accented chars

Comment: Would it work for converting from upper given table? Because i have lots of records in that table and i cannot do it manually.

Comment: you have to first make a script that updates your normalizedText with the non accented chars, then you can run any query on it

Comment: ok thanks for your response, will update you after trying this solution.

Comment: i came up with this solution but was not sure how to remove accents.