# Search in text by ASCII hex code using PHP

Tags: php, ascii, preg-replace

Good day! There is text in win1252 that contains symbols that shows like `0x9D` in Sublime text editor.

Help please with advice how it possible to find and replace all of them using PHP?

Comment: one code example?

Comment: When sublime shows `0x9D` do you have any reference at hand what that means in Sublime? Which encodings does Sublime support? And you ask about search and replace - with what do you want to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function.

`preg_replace('/\x9D/', '', $input);`

If source code in cp1252 encoding.
Add `u` modifier if source string is in utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all non-ASCII characters (bytes) in a file (that are all with the most significant 8th bit set), you can create a character class in PCRE to match all of those: `[\x80-\xFF]`. Compare [SQUARE BRACKETS AND CHARACTER CLASSES](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC9) and [BACKSLASH](https://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC5).

You can then replace all of them with `$result =` [`preg_replace`](https://php.net/preg_replace)`('~[\x80-\xFF]~', 'your replacement string', $subject);`. If you need a conditional replacement based on the actual byte value, see [`preg_replace_callback`](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback)`()` for replacing with a callback function.

You *may* also want to replace `DEL` so you can start the class at `\x7F` instead of `\x80`.

---

For Q&A material on how to apply this on a file, please see [*PHP preg_replace in a file?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33567286/367456).