# How to encode accented char

Tags: php, utf-8, internationalization, diacritics, iconv

I am using php and getting some utf8 string from Javascript.

I try to remove accent... by using a lot of difference function but still have troubles...
With `iconv()` I have wrong accent removing, with some encode() I have nothing...

When I use `serialize(mystring)`, my wrong char look like followings:
xE3xA0 with A0 depending of the char.

It there any exhaustive map I can use ?
Is there another method ?

(I am under php 5.2 and no real control on the server so I cannot use intl/Normalize)

---

Edit :
code like this doesnt works (otherwise it would be ugly but efficient for short term)

```
 $string = mb_ereg_replace('(À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å|à|á|â|ã|ä|å)','a',$string);
```

Comment: I try with  $word = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $word);

and iconv('ISO-8859-1' ...); 

And also by setting setlocale()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", $text)
```

If this does not work for you, see "[How do I remove accents from characters in a PHP string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017599/how-do-i-remove-accents-from-characters-in-a-php-string)"

Comment: as I said iconv seems not work (what ever is the first argument : UTF or ISO 88...)

Answer (score 0):

For simple cases, like words or small sentences, I always use [Sjoerd answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7635557/how-to-encode-accented-char/7635608#7635608) and it does work. For more complex cases such as long and complex paragraphs, possibly including some html, I use [HTMLPurifier library](http://htmlpurifier.org/) with this set of options

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('Core.Encoding', 'utf-8');
$config->set('Core.EscapeNonASCIICharacters', true);
$config->set('Cache.SerializerPath', sys_get_temp_dir());
$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'a[href],strong,b,i,p');
$config->set('HTML.TidyLevel', 'heavy');
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);
echo $purifier->purify('òàòààòòààè');
```

It will replace any non ASCII char to its corresponding HTML entity, in this way you get rid of all encoding problems for such strings. For instance `òàòààòòààè` will become `&#224;&#242;&#224;&#242;&#232;&#224;&#242;&#232;&#224;&#242;&#232;` which is encode friendly because it doesn't contain any non-ASCII char.

P.S. in any case don't use `preg_replace` for this kind of tasks, it's unsafe because you can't list all the possible non ASCII chars in a regex (or better, you could but it's pretty error prone task).

P.P.S. here is [a good document on utf-8 encoding](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html) and conversion in php taken from HTMLPurifier website.