# PHP MySQL search cyrillic characters

Tags: php, mysql, search, cyrillic

I would like to optimize my search sql query from cyrillic input.

If the user enters 'čšž' database return results with 'čšž' and 'csz'.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE name = ?");
```

SQL or PHP should convert character to non cyrillic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `UTF8_unicode_ci` collation for your column (or table or whole database) and then database should handle all that you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick using [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php):

```
// your input
$input = "Fóø Bår";

setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");

// this will remove accents and output standard ascii characters
$output = iconv("utf-8", "ascii//TRANSLIT", $input);

// do whatever you want with your output, for example use it in your MySQL query
// or just "echo" it, for demonstration
echo $output;
```

Note that this may [not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017599/how-do-i-remove-accents-from-characters-in-a-php-string) when a wrong version of `iconv` is installed on the server.

> The server is using the wrong implementation of iconv. It has the glibc version instead of the required libiconv version.

In that case, you may use this ugly hack that will work for most cases :

```
function stripAccents($stripAccents){
  return strtr($stripAccents,'àáâãäçèéêëìíîïñòóôõöùúûüýÿÀÁÂÃÄÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÑÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝ','aaaaaceeeeiiiinooooouuuuyyAAAAACEEEEIIIINOOOOOUUUUY');
}
```

*Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017599/how-do-i-remove-accents-from-characters-in-a-php-string/6443862#6443862).*

Comment: Thanks, stripAccents is good but I need some for SQL

I need to user inputs 'ščž' equals 'ščž' and 'scz' AND if user type in search 'scz' equals 'ščž' and 'scz'. With this I want to maximize my search results.

Comment: Use a query that will look for both values, something like `SELECT * WHERE value LIKE "%without_accents%" OR value LIKE "%with_accents%"`, just make sure to correctly escape both values so that you don't create an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).