# PHP keeps saving files with wrong characters

Tags: php, file, filter, special-characters, diacritics

my first question, don't kill me; I know this has been asked and I have read a lot of answers, but still can't figure it out.
I have a simple form, which uploads a file to my server (which I'm currently running with xampp on my computer).
I compose the name of the file from various inputs (2 of them are input type text).
But I can't find a way for the file to save correctly when someone inputs accents or the letter "ñ".
I've tried the function in this answer:
[How do I remove accents from characters in a PHP string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017599/how-do-i-remove-accents-from-characters-in-a-php-string)
Which is

```
function remove_accents($string) {
if ( !preg_match('/[\x80-\xff]/', $string) )
    return $string;

$chars = array(
// Decompositions for Latin-1 Supplement
chr(195).chr(128) => 'A', chr(195).chr(129) => 'A',
chr(195).chr(130) => 'A', chr(195).chr(131) => 'A',
chr(195).chr(132) => 'A', chr(195).chr(133) => 'A',
chr(195).chr(135) => 'C', chr(195).chr(136) => 'E',
chr(195).chr(137) => 'E', chr(195).chr(138) => 'E',
chr(195).chr(139) => 'E', chr(195).chr(140) => 'I',
chr(195).chr(141) => 'I', chr(195).chr(142) => 'I',
chr(195).chr(143) => 'I', chr(195).chr(145) => 'N',
chr(195).chr(146) => 'O', chr(195).chr(147) => 'O',
chr(195).chr(148) => 'O', chr(195).chr(149) => 'O',
chr(195).chr(150) => 'O', chr(195).chr(153) => 'U',
chr(195).chr(154) => 'U', chr(195).chr(155) => 'U',
chr(195).chr(156) => 'U', chr(195).chr(157) => 'Y',
chr(195).chr(159) => 's', chr(195).chr(160) => 'a',
chr(195).chr(161) => 'a', chr(195).chr(162) => 'a',
chr(195).chr(163) => 'a', chr(195).chr(164) => 'a',
chr(195).chr(165) => 'a', chr(195).chr(167) => 'c',
chr(195).chr(168) => 'e', chr(195).chr(169) => 'e',
chr(195).chr(170) => 'e', chr(195).chr(171) => 'e',
chr(195).chr(172) => 'i', chr(195).chr(173) => 'i',
chr(195).chr(174) => 'i', chr(195).chr(175) => 'i',
chr(195).chr(177) => 'n', chr(195).chr(178) => 'o',
chr(195).chr(179) => 'o', chr(195).chr(180) => 'o',
chr(195).chr(181) => 'o', chr(195).chr(182) => 'o',
chr(195).chr(182) => 'o', chr(195).chr(185) => 'u',
chr(195).chr(186) => 'u', chr(195).chr(187) => 'u',
chr(195).chr(188) => 'u', chr(195).chr(189) => 'y',
chr(195).chr(191) => 'y',
// Decompositions for Latin Extended-A
chr(196).chr(128) => 'A', chr(196).chr(129) => 'a',
chr(196).chr(130) => 'A', chr(196).chr(131) => 'a',
chr(196).chr(132) => 'A', chr(196).chr(133) => 'a',
chr(196).chr(134) => 'C', chr(196).chr(135) => 'c',
chr(196).chr(136) => 'C', chr(196).chr(137) => 'c',
chr(196).chr(138) => 'C', chr(196).chr(139) => 'c',
chr(196).chr(140) => 'C', chr(196).chr(141) => 'c',
chr(196).chr(142) => 'D', chr(196).chr(143) => 'd',
chr(196).chr(144) => 'D', chr(196).chr(145) => 'd',
chr(196).chr(146) => 'E', chr(196).chr(147) => 'e',
chr(196).chr(148) => 'E', chr(196).chr(149) => 'e',
chr(196).chr(150) => 'E', chr(196).chr(151) => 'e',
chr(196).chr(152) => 'E', chr(196).chr(153) => 'e',
chr(196).chr(154) => 'E', chr(196).chr(155) => 'e',
chr(196).chr(156) => 'G', chr(196).chr(157) => 'g',
chr(196).chr(158) => 'G', chr(196).chr(159) => 'g',
chr(196).chr(160) => 'G', chr(196).chr(161) => 'g',
chr(196).chr(162) => 'G', chr(196).chr(163) => 'g',
chr(196).chr(164) => 'H', chr(196).chr(165) => 'h',
chr(196).chr(166) => 'H', chr(196).chr(167) => 'h',
chr(196).chr(168) => 'I', chr(196).chr(169) => 'i',
chr(196).chr(170) => 'I', chr(196).chr(171) => 'i',
chr(196).chr(172) => 'I', chr(196).chr(173) => 'i',
chr(196).chr(174) => 'I', chr(196).chr(175) => 'i',
chr(196).chr(176) => 'I', chr(196).chr(177) => 'i',
chr(196).chr(178) => 'IJ',chr(196).chr(179) => 'ij',
chr(196).chr(180) => 'J', chr(196).chr(181) => 'j',
chr(196).chr(182) => 'K', chr(196).chr(183) => 'k',
chr(196).chr(184) => 'k', chr(196).chr(185) => 'L',
chr(196).chr(186) => 'l', chr(196).chr(187) => 'L',
chr(196).chr(188) => 'l', chr(196).chr(189) => 'L',
chr(196).chr(190) => 'l', chr(196).chr(191) => 'L',
chr(197).chr(128) => 'l', chr(197).chr(129) => 'L',
chr(197).chr(130) => 'l', chr(197).chr(131) => 'N',
chr(197).chr(132) => 'n', chr(197).chr(133) => 'N',
chr(197).chr(134) => 'n', chr(197).chr(135) => 'N',
chr(197).chr(136) => 'n', chr(197).chr(137) => 'N',
chr(197).chr(138) => 'n', chr(197).chr(139) => 'N',
chr(197).chr(140) => 'O', chr(197).chr(141) => 'o',
chr(197).chr(142) => 'O', chr(197).chr(143) => 'o',
chr(197).chr(144) => 'O', chr(197).chr(145) => 'o',
chr(197).chr(146) => 'OE',chr(197).chr(147) => 'oe',
chr(197).chr(148) => 'R',chr(197).chr(149) => 'r',
chr(197).chr(150) => 'R',chr(197).chr(151) => 'r',
chr(197).chr(152) => 'R',chr(197).chr(153) => 'r',
chr(197).chr(154) => 'S',chr(197).chr(155) => 's',
chr(197).chr(156) => 'S',chr(197).chr(157) => 's',
chr(197).chr(158) => 'S',chr(197).chr(159) => 's',
chr(197).chr(160) => 'S', chr(197).chr(161) => 's',
chr(197).chr(162) => 'T', chr(197).chr(163) => 't',
chr(197).chr(164) => 'T', chr(197).chr(165) => 't',
chr(197).chr(166) => 'T', chr(197).chr(167) => 't',
chr(197).chr(168) => 'U', chr(197).chr(169) => 'u',
chr(197).chr(170) => 'U', chr(197).chr(171) => 'u',
chr(197).chr(172) => 'U', chr(197).chr(173) => 'u',
chr(197).chr(174) => 'U', chr(197).chr(175) => 'u',
chr(197).chr(176) => 'U', chr(197).chr(177) => 'u',
chr(197).chr(178) => 'U', chr(197).chr(179) => 'u',
chr(197).chr(180) => 'W', chr(197).chr(181) => 'w',
chr(197).chr(182) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(183) => 'y',
chr(197).chr(184) => 'Y', chr(197).chr(185) => 'Z',
chr(197).chr(186) => 'z', chr(197).chr(187) => 'Z',
chr(197).chr(188) => 'z', chr(197).chr(189) => 'Z',
chr(197).chr(190) => 'z', chr(197).chr(191) => 's'
);

$string = strtr($string, $chars);

return $string; }
```

And I've also tried this function (which I don't have the link now but it was in some thread too)

```
function str_file_filter(
$str,
$sep = '_',
$strict = false,
$trim = 248) {

$str = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars_decode(strtolower($str))); // lowercase -> decode -> strip tags
$str = str_replace("%20", ' ', $str); // convert rogue %20s into spaces
$str = preg_replace("/%[a-z0-9]{1,2}/i", '', $str); // remove hexy things
$str = str_replace("&nbsp;", ' ', $str); // convert all nbsp into space
$str = preg_replace("/&#?[a-z0-9]{2,8};/i", '', $str); // remove the other non-tag things
$str = preg_replace("/\s+/", $sep, $str); // filter multiple spaces
$str = preg_replace("/\.+/", '.', $str); // filter multiple periods
$str = preg_replace("/^\.+/", '', $str); // trim leading period

if ($strict) {
    $str = preg_replace("/([^\w\d\\" . $sep . ".])/", '', $str); // only allow words and digits
} else {
    $str = preg_replace("/([^\w\d\\" . $sep . "\[\]\(\).])/", '', $str); // allow words, digits, [], and ()
}

$str = preg_replace("/\\" . $sep . "+/", $sep, $str); // filter multiple separators
$str = substr($str, 0, $trim); // trim filename to desired length, note 255 char limit on windows

return $str; }
```

Both fuctions do the work correctly, the first one replaces the characters and the second one removes them (and various other illegal).
If I echo the output of those functions, I see them perfectly fine, let's supose I enter "níño" the first one gives me "nino" and the second one "no".
But nonetheless when I save the file, it creates it with "Ã©bÃ¡" or stuff like that.
What am I doing wrong, or is there something I haven't changed in apache or php config?.

My php.ini file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3181x8rlmm1kiqp/php.ini?dl=0

Comment: Did you try to define the charset in the head tag of your page ? <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: If you use unicode characters, **use** the MultiByte extension. How do you save the file?

Comment: Yes, meta charset is set; but as I understand, how php saves the files doesn't have anything to do with html doesn't it?

Comment: I save the files with move_uploaded_files(TMP locaction, new location and name composed of those sanitized strings)

Comment: I added my php.ini file in the initial post, I don't know if all the options in mbstring are correct