# Laravel - function like string replace?

Tags: laravel, str-replace

I have a little problem. I've build a tagging system and it mostly work. The only problem is that I get error messages if I use special characters.

Like: ä, ö, ü, ß, Ì, é, è,ë and so on....

If I change ä to ae, or Ì to I ..... then it all work.

Now I don't like to write about 20-60 different str_replace commands.. So, does someone knows a solution for that?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked these questions?

[Replacing accented characters php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php)

[How do I remove accents from characters in a PHP string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017599/how-do-i-remove-accents-from-characters-in-a-php-string)

I'm afraid there is no straightforward one-command solution to your question and you will end up with one huge character map. Mostly because different use cases imply different substitutions. Some cases require `ä` mapped to `a` because of string sorting, others prefer to have `ä` mapped to `ae` because of readability.

Comment: Well, that works.. I don't like it, but its okay. But its the same with arabic letters, chinese letters and so on... And I don't really want to insert every letter on the world, I don't want for this problem..

Comment: Look into the solutions using `iconv` but there are not many people who succeeded to make it work consistently :) I don't think the problem of converting chinese characters to latin alphabet even has a straightforward solution.