# PHP Iconv adding extra characters

Tags: php, utf-8, translation, iconv

I'm trying to remove all the accents etc from some text in PHP using iconv. It strips the accents but sometimes adds an extra character, for example:
`"Théâtre"` comes out as `"Th'e^atre"` whereas I want `"Theatre"`

Here is my code:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.utf8");
$text = "Théâtre";
$text = iconv("utf-8","ascii//TRANSLIT//IGNORE",$text);
echo $text;
```

Result: Th'e^atre

Comment: What operating system are you running PHP on and what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: for me it's working btw need some ; at 2 and 4 line...

Comment: This works when I test it on both PHP 7.0 and 5.6.29. I added `;` to the code as this seems to be a typo, @Spizzi .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is probably due to a wrong implemantation of `iconv()` on your server (**glibc** instead of **libiconv**, you can check it in the output of `phpinfo()`). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017599/how-do-i-remove-accents-from-characters-in-a-php-string?rq=1) for more details.

You can also try :

```
$text = "Théâtre";
$text = iconv("utf-8","ascii//TRANSLIT",$text); //$text = "Th'e^atre"
//Replace any character not in alphabet by an empty substring.
$text = preg_replace("#[^a-zA-z]#", "", $text); //$text = "Theatre"

echo $text;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked phpinfo() and under iconv it says: iconv implementation=libiconv and
iconv library version=1.14

Comment: Because I cannot change the PHP environment this project is destined for, this solution doesn't work for me, neither does removing the non-alpha characters because some of the text may contain characters I want to keep. However the question linked to has an answer that mentions the Wordpress implementation and this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this was to use the Wordpress implementation. Not pretty but in the end nothing else did the trick

```
function remove_accents( $string ) {
if ( !preg_match('/[\x80-\xff]/', $string) )
    return $string;

$chars = array(
// Decompositions for Latin-1 Supplement
'ª' => 'a', 'º' => 'o',
'À' => 'A', 'Á' => 'A',
'Â' => 'A', 'Ã' => 'A',
'Ä' => 'A', 'Å' => 'A',
'Æ' => 'AE','Ç' => 'C',
'È' => 'E', 'É' => 'E',
'Ê' => 'E', 'Ë' => 'E',
'Ì' => 'I', 'Í' => 'I',
'Î' => 'I', 'Ï' => 'I',
'Ð' => 'D', 'Ñ' => 'N',
'Ò' => 'O', 'Ó' => 'O',
'Ô' => 'O', 'Õ' => 'O',
'Ö' => 'O', 'Ù' => 'U',
'Ú' => 'U', 'Û' => 'U',
'Ü' => 'U', 'Ý' => 'Y',
'Þ' => 'TH','ß' => 's',
'à' => 'a', 'á' => 'a',
'â' => 'a', 'ã' => 'a',
'ä' => 'a', 'å' => 'a',
'æ' => 'ae','ç' => 'c',
'è' => 'e', 'é' => 'e',
'ê' => 'e', 'ë' => 'e',
'ì' => 'i', 'í' => 'i',
'î' => 'i', 'ï' => 'i',
'ð' => 'd', 'ñ' => 'n',
'ò' => 'o', 'ó' => 'o',
'ô' => 'o', 'õ' => 'o',
'ö' => 'o', 'ø' => 'o',
'ù' => 'u', 'ú' => 'u',
'û' => 'u', 'ü' => 'u',
'ý' => 'y', 'þ' => 'th',
'ÿ' => 'y', 'Ø' => 'O',
// Decompositions for Latin Extended-A
'Ā' => 'A', 'ā' => 'a',
'Ă' => 'A', 'ă' => 'a',
'Ą' => 'A', 'ą' => 'a',
'Ć' => 'C', 'ć' => 'c',
'Ĉ' => 'C', 'ĉ' => 'c',
'Ċ' => 'C', 'ċ' => 'c',
'Č' => 'C', 'č' => 'c',
'Ď' => 'D', 'ď' => 'd',
'Đ' => 'D', 'đ' => 'd',
'Ē' => 'E', 'ē' => 'e',
'Ĕ' => 'E', 'ĕ' => 'e',
'Ė' => 'E', 'ė' => 'e',
'Ę' => 'E', 'ę' => 'e',
'Ě' => 'E', 'ě' => 'e',
'Ĝ' => 'G', 'ĝ' => 'g',
'Ğ' => 'G', 'ğ' => 'g',
'Ġ' => 'G', 'ġ' => 'g',
'Ģ' => 'G', 'ģ' => 'g',
'Ĥ' => 'H', 'ĥ' => 'h',
'Ħ' => 'H', 'ħ' => 'h',
'Ĩ' => 'I', 'ĩ' => 'i',
'Ī' => 'I', 'ī' => 'i',
'Ĭ' => 'I', 'ĭ' => 'i',
'Į' => 'I', 'į' => 'i',
'İ' => 'I', 'ı' => 'i',
'Ĳ' => 'IJ','ĳ' => 'ij',
'Ĵ' => 'J', 'ĵ' => 'j',
'Ķ' => 'K', 'ķ' => 'k',
'ĸ' => 'k', 'Ĺ' => 'L',
'ĺ' => 'l', 'Ļ' => 'L',
'ļ' => 'l', 'Ľ' => 'L',
'ľ' => 'l', 'Ŀ' => 'L',
'ŀ' => 'l', 'Ł' => 'L',
'ł' => 'l', 'Ń' => 'N',
'ń' => 'n', 'Ņ' => 'N',
'ņ' => 'n', 'Ň' => 'N',
'ň' => 'n', 'ŉ' => 'n',
'Ŋ' => 'N', 'ŋ' => 'n',
'Ō' => 'O', 'ō' => 'o',
'Ŏ' => 'O', 'ŏ' => 'o',
'Ő' => 'O', 'ő' => 'o',
'Œ' => 'OE','œ' => 'oe',
'Ŕ' => 'R','ŕ' => 'r',
'Ŗ' => 'R','ŗ' => 'r',
'Ř' => 'R','ř' => 'r',
'Ś' => 'S','ś' => 's',
'Ŝ' => 'S','ŝ' => 's',
'Ş' => 'S','ş' => 's',
'Š' => 'S', 'š' => 's',
'Ţ' => 'T', 'ţ' => 't',
'Ť' => 'T', 'ť' => 't',
'Ŧ' => 'T', 'ŧ' => 't',
'Ũ' => 'U', 'ũ' => 'u',
'Ū' => 'U', 'ū' => 'u',
'Ŭ' => 'U', 'ŭ' => 'u',
'Ů' => 'U', 'ů' => 'u',
'Ű' => 'U', 'ű' => 'u',
'Ų' => 'U', 'ų' => 'u',
'Ŵ' => 'W', 'ŵ' => 'w',
'Ŷ' => 'Y', 'ŷ' => 'y',
'Ÿ' => 'Y', 'Ź' => 'Z',
'ź' => 'z', 'Ż' => 'Z',
'ż' => 'z', 'Ž' => 'Z',
'ž' => 'z', 'ſ' => 's',
// Decompositions for Latin Extended-B
'Ș' => 'S', 'ș' => 's',
'Ț' => 'T', 'ț' => 't',
// Euro Sign
'€' => 'E',
// GBP (Pound) Sign
'£' => '',
// Vowels with diacritic (Vietnamese)
// unmarked
'Ơ' => 'O', 'ơ' => 'o',
'Ư' => 'U', 'ư' => 'u',
// grave accent
'Ầ' => 'A', 'ầ' => 'a',
'Ằ' => 'A', 'ằ' => 'a',
'Ề' => 'E', 'ề' => 'e',
'Ồ' => 'O', 'ồ' => 'o',
'Ờ' => 'O', 'ờ' => 'o',
'Ừ' => 'U', 'ừ' => 'u',
'Ỳ' => 'Y', 'ỳ' => 'y',
// hook
'Ả' => 'A', 'ả' => 'a',
'Ẩ' => 'A', 'ẩ' => 'a',
'Ẳ' => 'A', 'ẳ' => 'a',
'Ẻ' => 'E', 'ẻ' => 'e',
'Ể' => 'E', 'ể' => 'e',
'Ỉ' => 'I', 'ỉ' => 'i',
'Ỏ' => 'O', 'ỏ' => 'o',
'Ổ' => 'O', 'ổ' => 'o',
'Ở' => 'O', 'ở' => 'o',
'Ủ' => 'U', 'ủ' => 'u',
'Ử' => 'U', 'ử' => 'u',
'Ỷ' => 'Y', 'ỷ' => 'y',
// tilde
'Ẫ' => 'A', 'ẫ' => 'a',
'Ẵ' => 'A', 'ẵ' => 'a',
'Ẽ' => 'E', 'ẽ' => 'e',
'Ễ' => 'E', 'ễ' => 'e',
'Ỗ' => 'O', 'ỗ' => 'o',
'Ỡ' => 'O', 'ỡ' => 'o',
'Ữ' => 'U', 'ữ' => 'u',
'Ỹ' => 'Y', 'ỹ' => 'y',
// acute accent
'Ấ' => 'A', 'ấ' => 'a',
'Ắ' => 'A', 'ắ' => 'a',
'Ế' => 'E', 'ế' => 'e',
'Ố' => 'O', 'ố' => 'o',
'Ớ' => 'O', 'ớ' => 'o',
'Ứ' => 'U', 'ứ' => 'u',
// dot below
'Ạ' => 'A', 'ạ' => 'a',
'Ậ' => 'A', 'ậ' => 'a',
'Ặ' => 'A', 'ặ' => 'a',
'Ẹ' => 'E', 'ẹ' => 'e',
'Ệ' => 'E', 'ệ' => 'e',
'Ị' => 'I', 'ị' => 'i',
'Ọ' => 'O', 'ọ' => 'o',
'Ộ' => 'O', 'ộ' => 'o',
'Ợ' => 'O', 'ợ' => 'o',
'Ụ' => 'U', 'ụ' => 'u',
'Ự' => 'U', 'ự' => 'u',
'Ỵ' => 'Y', 'ỵ' => 'y',
// Vowels with diacritic (Chinese, Hanyu Pinyin)
'ɑ' => 'a',
// macron
'Ǖ' => 'U', 'ǖ' => 'u',
// acute accent
'Ǘ' => 'U', 'ǘ' => 'u',
// caron
'Ǎ' => 'A', 'ǎ' => 'a',
'Ǐ' => 'I', 'ǐ' => 'i',
'Ǒ' => 'O', 'ǒ' => 'o',
'Ǔ' => 'U', 'ǔ' => 'u',
'Ǚ' => 'U', 'ǚ' => 'u',
// grave accent
'Ǜ' => 'U', 'ǜ' => 'u',
);

$string = strtr($string, $chars);

return $string;
}
```