# How to replace accented and lowercase characters in PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I have a PHP code that actually load the data from a form and then save it as a XML file.
It´s needed to setup a rule where accentuation and lowercasse characters are not allowed in the form. In order words, the output XML file attributes elements field need to be filled with **UPPERCASE** and can **NOT BE ACCENTUATED**.

Is there a way to set this "rule" into my PHP code??

Even if the final user input lowercase characters and/or accentuation?

**Eg. User Input (form field called Name/Address):**

Name: John

Address: Ratão

**File Output:**

`<attribute domainname="Name">JOHN</attribute>`

`<attribute domainname="Address">RATAO</attribute>`

**PHP Code: (Actual)**

```
    $domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute', $posted_data['name']);
    $domAttribute = $domDocument->createAttribute('domainname');
    $domAttribute->value = 'Name';

    $domElement = $domDocument->createElement('attribute', $posted_data['address']);
    $domAttribute = $domDocument->createAttribute('domainname');
    $domAttribute->value = 'Address';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/a/32562697

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strtoupper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) and [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php).

```
// get the value
$value = isset($_POST['nameOfField']) ? $_POST['nameOfField'] : '';
// set the locale
setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8");  
// replace accents
$value = iconv('UTF-8','ASCII//TRANSLIT',$value);
//make upper case
$value = strtoupper($value);
```

More on replacing accents in string: [Replacing accented characters php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371697/replacing-accented-characters-php)