# Command SED in PHP

Tags: php, regex, linux

How can I do search and replace in a file with the sed command, since I'm currently getting an error.

```
$command = "sed -i \"y/\xE1\xE9\xED\xF3\xFA\xF1\xC1\xC9\xCD\xD3\xDA\xD1/aeiounAEIOUN/\" file.txt";

exec($command);
```

I have a .php file from which I execute the previously mentioned command where I intend to eliminate special characters from a .txt file but when doing php script.php I get that error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `"'

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried running that command manually? What makes you think that this is in any way related to PHP?

Comment: Is this what you expected? https://3v4l.org/ZE9OX Try with single quotes.

Comment: already try single and double quotes. What I intend is to execute the following command: **sed -i 'and / áÁààããââÉÉÉÊÊÍÍóÓõÕôÔúÚñÑçÇ / aAaAaAaAeEeEiIoOoOoOuUnNcC /'** file but from php.

Comment: A simple `echo $command` would give you an idea what it's trying to do. You're aware that `\xE1` is going to get interpreted by PHP and not sed, right? Also, this is classic X/Y problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017599/how-do-i-remove-accents-from-characters-in-a-php-string

Comment: And finally, why would you want to remove accents? I don't know a lot of Spanish but I know the difference between año and ano.