# How to sort accented letters using ksort in php?

Tags: php, ksort

I am working on a php code as shown below:

```
<?php
$age=array("Bam"=>"35","Bân"=>"37","Bao"=>"43");
ksort($age);

foreach($age as $x=>$x_value)
   {
   echo "Key=" . $x . ", Value=" . $x_value;
   echo "<br>";
   }
?>
```

The above php code display the following o/p:

```
Key=Bam, Value=35
Key=Bao, Value=43
Key=Bân, Value=37
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code above so that it display the following o/p:

```
Key=Bam, Value=35
Key=Bân, Value=37
Key=Bao, Value=43
```

Comment: Sorting is based on rules, why do think `â` comes between `a` and `a`? They are not the same.

Comment: The last alphabet m comes 1st then n and o.

Comment: So you want to sort WITHOUT the accents considered?

Comment: Yes, I want to sort without the accents considered.

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with some of the locale-based methods suggested, but eventually the only way I was able to get it to work was to use one of the `remove_accents` functions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017599/how-do-i-remove-accents-from-characters-in-a-php-string) and then sort the array according to the order of the unaccented keys.

```
$unaccented = array_map('remove_accents', array_keys($age));
array_multisort($unaccented, $age);
```

Doesn't mean it won't work with `setlocale` etc, just that I wasn't able to make it work, but this may be a viable alternative.