# Reduce a UTF-8 string for binary comparison

Tags: php, icu, intl

**I want to quickly check if an UTF-8 word exists as an array key.**

The words may have:

- different case
- accented characters or not
- different Unicode normalization forms

I can use `mb_strtolower()` to make them both lowercase, and `Normalizer::normalize()` to normalize the strings. This checks the first 2 bullet points, but does not handle accents:

```php
'tést' !== 'test'
```

I can use `Collator` to compare both words:

```php
$collator = new Collator('fr_FR');
$collator->setStrength(Collator::PRIMARY);
$collator->compare('tést', 'test'); // 0
```

This checks my 3 bullet points, but I now I have to loop over all my word pairs to compare them, when I want to be able to perform a binary lookup as an array key (I have many lookups to perform on a big dictionary).

What I want is:

```php
function reduce($word) {
    // how?
}

// prepare the dictionary (once)

$dictionary = [];

foreach ($dictionaryWords as $dictionaryWord) {
    $dictionary[reduce($dictionaryWord)] = true;
}

// perform a lookup (many times)

if (isset($dictionary[reduce($lookupWord)])) {
    // it's a match!
}
```

Basically, I want the `reduce()` function (which may be poorly named) to perform a simplification like this one:

- 'TÈST' => 'test'
- 'Straße' => 'strasse'

I believe MySQL does something like this internally for its text indexes.

**Is there an `intl` function that does this?** The [list of `intl` classes and functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) is hard to digest.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017599/how-do-i-remove-accents-from-characters-in-a-php-string might have what you need

Comment: @Pete Most of the answers on this page are about hardcoding character maps, which is the poor man's solution to this problem. However, I can see deep down an answer about `Transliterator`, which may be what I'm looking for. I will test this and report the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm looking for is the [Transliterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.transliterator.php) class. An example can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35177899/759866):

```php
$string = "Fóø Bår";
$transliterator = Transliterator::createFromRules(':: Any-Latin; :: Latin-ASCII; :: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: Lower(); :: NFC;', Transliterator::FORWARD);
echo $transliterator->transliterate($string); // foo bar
```

Thanks to [@Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12014552/pete) for the pointer in the comments.

This even works with non-european characters:

```
echo $transliterator->transliterate('Fóø Bår 学中文'); foo bar xue zhong wen
```

Where `iconv` would fail at the job:

```
echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', 'Fóø Bår 学中文'); // Foo Bar ???
```

Unless I'm missing some other `iconv` options, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question, it seems that you're only really interested in checking if a word exists as a unique array index.

You could do this by cryptographically hashing the word and using the hash as the index. It would go something like this:

```
<?php
$word = 'TÈST';
$dictionary[sha1($word)] = TRUE;
```

Or use an algorithm that is more resilient to collision attacks, if that is a concern to you. Please elaborate your question if you need any pointers in that area.

**UPDATE**

Please see the snippet below, which produces "test, strasse".

```
<?php

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'nl_NL.UTF-8');

$words = [ 'TÈST', 'Straße' ];

foreach ($words as $index => $word)
{
    echo ($index?', ':'') . strtolower(iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $word));
}
```

Comment: It looks like you did not properly read, or understand, the question. Your solution would fail if I'm looking for `'test'`, as `sha1('test') !== sha1('TÈST')`. This question is about collations, not about cryptographic hashes.

Comment: Perhaps. Perhaps you could have phrased it better. Please check out my update.