# How to remove Vietnamese accents for web urls?

Tags: .htaccess, web, url, hyperlink

I'm having difficulty removing marks on web urls by inserting them into **htaccess.**

current link : https://vizi.vn/read-blog/24428_tim-hi%E1%BB%83u-d%E1%BA%A5u-g%E1%BA%A1ch-cheo-cu%E1%BB%91i-url-c%E1%BA%A7n-hay-khong-c%E1%BA%A7n-%E1%BA%A3nh-h%C6%B0%E1%BB%9Fng-%C4%91%E1%BA%BFn-seo-nh%C6%B0-th%E1%BA%BF-nao.html

How do I make it a link like this?
https:/vizi.vn/read-blog/24428_tim-hieu-dau-gach-cheo-cuoi-url-can-hay-khong-can-anh-huong-đen-seo-nhu-the-nao.html

[vizi.vn](https://vizi.vn/read-blog/24428_tim-hieu-dau-gach-cheo-cuoi-url-can-hay-khong-can-anh-huong-%C4%91en-seo-nhu-the-nao.html)

thanks

How do I make it a link like this?
https:/vizi.vn/read-blog/24428_tim-hieu-dau-gach-cheo-cuoi-url-can-hay-khong-can-anh-huong-đen-seo-nhu-the-nao.html

Comment: URL rewriting doesn't "make links", it redirects or rewrites incoming requests to something else. If you want to remove characters out of the English/ASCII range form the link on your site, then you should do that when you are _creating_ those links. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1017599/1427878 has some hints on how to get started for PHP; if you are using a different server-side language to manage your content, then do a bit more research.