2 similar strings evaluated incorrectly
I have the below function to compare word in database with word the user searches for.It return true when there is a match and false if not. Some of the words have special /Unicode characters so we have to code in a way that it can fetch results when man uses normal alphabet counterparts of the special characters (e.g DB contains entry for Müller, then it can be fetched if user types Muller/muller/Müller/müller)
public function string_contains_word(string $string, string $word): bool {
        // Handling non-ASCII  characters.
        
        $stringconv = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $string);
        $match_og = strpos(mb_strtolower($string), mb_strtolower($word)) !== false;
        $match_conv = strpos(mb_strtolower($stringconv), mb_strtolower($word)) !== false;
        $return_val = ($match_og !== false) ? $match_og : $match_conv;
        return $return_val;
    }

The evaluation works for most cases except for the below use case.
If the database has an entry Yiǧit in a course, when user search for

Yiğit -> does not return a result (NOT IDEAL)
Yiǧit -> returns a result (IDEAL)



I cannot visually see a difference between the 2 strings but when i run strcmp() on them
echo strcmp("Yiğit","Yiǧit");

it returns -3
Can anyone explain what the difference is and how can I reform the code so that the entry shows

"I cannot visually see a difference between the 2 strings" - I like to apply urlencode, when I'm not sure what byte values a string contains. Your first of those two results in Yi%C4%9Fit, the second one in Yi%C7%A7it. So the first of those ğ is c4 9f, that is code point U+011F, "LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH BREVE", and the second one, c7 a7 is cp U+01E7, "LATIN SMALL LETTER G WITH CARON"

I understand but is there a way to still show the result irrespective of whether the user uses BREVE or CARON? Because querying in DB does return the result for both cases

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35177899/3439404 (apply to both $string and $word)…
